# I need help understanding the rest and spread operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is the code:

```
const Pipe = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f,g) => (...args) => g(f(...args)));
```

So by (...fns) the fns arguments becomes an array right? in this part:

```
 (f,g) => (...args)
```

where did args came from? is there a default args parameter? and I cannot read this part:

```
(...args) => g(f(...args))
```

I just cannot wrap my head with this nesting and what reduce does here is so confusing.

Comment: Notice you've asked about the `(...args)` twice, associating it with two different parts of the code. `(...args) => g(f(...args))` is a function that has an argument called `args` (there is no default `args`). When you asked about `(f,g) => (...args)` you've split the original line in the wrong spot. It might help to add some extra parentheses: `(f,g) => ( (...args) => g(f(...args)) )` to see how things are grouped. In the above code, `.reduce()` is taking a single argument that is a function which returns another function.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better understanding I have translated the code to block level as below trying to explain the code in question for a novice developer which helps. For better implementation **@naomik** has solution.

**ES6**

```
const Pipe = (...fns) => {
    return fns.reduce((f, g) => {
        return (...args) => {
            return g(f(...args))
        }
    })
};
```

**Equivalent ES5 implementation:**

```
var Pipe = function () {
    var fns = [];
    for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
        fns[_i] = arguments[_i];
    }
    return fns.reduce(function (f, g) {
        return function () {
            var args = [];
            for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
                args[_i] = arguments[_i];
            }
            return g(f.apply(void 0/*Undefined or can use 'null'*/, args));
        };
    });
};
```

**Part by part breakdown:(read the code comments for better understanding)**

```
const inc = (num) => num+1 //Function to increment the number
const dbl = (num) => num*2 //Function double's the number
const sqr = (num) => num*num //Function Square's the number

/*Function breakdown*/
const _pipe = (f, g) => (...args) => g(f(...args)); //Second part
const Pipe = (...fns) => fns.reduce(_pipe); //First part

const incDblSqr = Pipe(inc, dbl, sqr) //Piping all the functions
const result = incDblSqr(2) // Piped function
console.log(result) // ((2+1)*2) ^ 2  = 36
```

**Explaination:**

The code in question helps to pipe the result from one function to another function.

*Step by step process of above code:*

- First number is incremented by 1
- The result after increment is accumulated and piped to another
  function where the number gets multiplied by 2 (doubling it)
- Finally the doubled number is squared next function.

All these are achieved using closures which has access to the reducing arguments *(Read the article linked below for clarity)*.

**Conclusion:**
The code in question helps to pipe the n-number of functions that operates     on the result emitted by previous function.

---

**Best article by Andrew L. Van Slaars:**
https://vanslaars.io/post/create-pipe-function/

***Please read the above article for clarity and also @naomik solution***

Answer (score 5):

Your first problem is you're dealing with a bad implementation of `pipe` – the second problem is there's a variety of spread syntaxes in new JavaScript and it's not always clear (to beginners) which one is being used where

**rest parameter**

a rest parameter collects the supplied arguments to a function in an array. This replaces the old `arguments` object of JavaScript's yesteryear

```js
const f = (...xs) =>
  xs
  
console.log(f())    // []
console.log(f(1))   // [1]
console.log(f(1,2)) // [1,2]
```

---

**spread arguments**

spread arguments allows you to spread an array (or any iterable) as arguments to a function call. This replaces (almost all) instances of `Function.prototype.apply`

```js
const g = (a,b,c) =>
  a + b + c
  
const args = [1,2,3]

console.log(g(...args)) // 6
```

---

**why that `pipe` is bad**

It's not a total function – `pipe`s domain is `[Function]` (array of functions), but this implementation will produce an error if an empty array of functions is used (`TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value`)

It might not be immediately apparent how this would happen, but it could come up in a variety of ways. Most notably, when the list of functions to apply is an array that was created elsewhere in your program and ends up being empty, `Pipe` fails catastrophically

```
const foo = Pipe()
foo(1)
// TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value

const funcs = []
Pipe(...funcs) (1)
// TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value

Pipe.apply(null, funcs) (1)
// TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value

Pipe.call(null) (1)
// TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
```

---

**reimplementing `pipe`**

This is one of countless implementations, but it should be a lot easier to understand. We have one use of a rest parameter, and one use of a spread argument. Most importantly, `pipe` **always** returns a function

```js
const pipe = (f,...fs) => x =>
  f === undefined ? x : pipe(...fs) (f(x))
  
const foo = pipe(
  x => x + 1,
  x => x * 2,
  x => x * x,
  console.log
)

foo(0) // 4
foo(1) // 16
foo(2) // 36

// empty pipe is ok
const bar = pipe()
console.log(bar(2)) // 2
```

---

***"but i heard recursion is bad"***

OK, so if you're going to pipe thousands of functions, you might run into a stack overflow. In such a case, you can use the stack-safe `Array.prototype.reduce` (or `reduceRight`) like in your original post.

This time instead of doing everything within `pipe`, I'm going to decompose the problem into smaller parts. Each part has a distinct purpose, and `pipe` is now only concerned with how the parts fit together.

```js
const comp = (f,g) => x =>
  f(g(x))

const identity = x =>
  x
  
const pipe = (...fs) =>
  fs.reduceRight(comp, identity)

const foo = pipe(
  x => x + 1,
  x => x * 2,
  x => x * x,
  console.log
)

foo(0) // 4
foo(1) // 16
foo(2) // 36

// empty pipe is ok
const bar = pipe()
console.log(bar(2)) // 2
```

---

***"I really just want to understand the code in my post though"***

OK, let's step thru your `pipe` function and see what's happening. Because `reduce` will call the reducing function multiple times, I'm going to use a unique renaming for `args` each time

```
// given
const Pipe = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f,g) => (...args) => g(f(...args)));

// evaluate
Pipe(a,b,c,d)

// environment:
fns = [a,b,c,d]

// reduce iteration 1 (renamed `args` to `x`)
(...x) => b(a(...x))

// reduce iteration 2 (renamed `args` to `y`)
(...y) => c((...x) => b(a(...x))(...y))

// reduce iteration 3 (renamed `args` to `z`)
(...z) => d((...y) => c((...x) => b(a(...x))(...y))(...z))
```

So what happens then when that function is applied? Let's have a look when we apply the result of `Pipe(a,b,c,d)` with some argument `Q`

```
// return value of Pipe(a,b,c,d) applied to `Q`
(...z) => d((...y) => c((...x) => b(a(...x))(...y))(...z)) (Q)

// substitute ...z for [Q]
d((...y) => c((...x) => b(a(...x))(...y))(...[Q]))

// spread [Q]
d((...y) => c((...x) => b(a(...x))(...y))(Q))

// substitute ...y for [Q]
d(c((...x) => b(a(...x))(...[Q]))

// spread [Q]
d(c((...x) => b(a(...x))(Q))

// substitute ...x for [Q]
d(c(b(a(...[Q])))

// spread [Q]
d(c(b(a(Q)))
```

So, just as we expected

```
// run
Pipe(a,b,c,d)(Q)

// evalutes to
d(c(b(a(Q))))
```

---

**additional reading**

I've done a lot of writing on the topic of function composition. I encourage you to explore some of these related questions/I've done a lot of writing on the topic of function composition. I encourage you to explore some of these related questions/answers

If anything, you'll probably see a different implementation of `compose` (or `pipe`, `flow`, et al) in each answer. Maybe one of them will speak to your higher conscience!

- [How to understand curry and function composition using Lodash flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42139851/633183)
- [lodash curry does not work on function returned by flow; lodash FP enough for FP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39047414/633183)
- [functional composition of a boolean 'not' function (not a boolean value)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42098875/633183)
- [How to compose functions of varying arity using Lodash flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42166494/633183)
- [How to reconcile Javascript with currying and function composition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42164779/633183)

Comment: When you say "spread parameter" it should really be called "rest parameter".

Answer (score 0):

Well @naomik beat me to just about the same answer but I thought I'd still share what I had to help you explain how the function works in a possibly less cryptic way. (Maybe)

I think you already know how the "`...`" works (and in case you didn't then naomik's answer should help with that :D)

Here is another version of that same pipe function expect re-written to better explain what's going on using assignments just to explain the point.

Array.prototype.reduce calls the "reducer", `toASingleFunction`, multiple times--one call for each function in `functionsToPipe`. The `currentFunctionToPipe` is first `x => x + 1` then `x => x * 2` and so on...

The first value of `newFunction` is `theIdentityFunction` and the reducer returns another function `nextNewFunction`. As the name suggests, it becomes the next `newFunction` in the next call to the "reducer" (`toASingleFunction`).

Once all the items in `functionsToPipe` have been reduced, the final `newFunction` is returned as `finalPipeFunction`.

```js
/**
 * `x` goes to itself
 */
const theIdentityFunction = x => x;

/**
 * the `reducer` that reduces the array of functions into a single function
 * using the value from the last function as the input to the next function
 */
const toASingleFunction = (newFunction, currentFunctionToPipe) => {
  const nextNewFunction = function(value) { // i'm not using arrow functions here just to explicitly show that `nextNewFunction` is, in fact, a function
    const valueFromLastFunction = newFunction(value);
    return currentFunctionToPipe(valueFromLastFunction);
  }
  return nextNewFunction;
};

const pipe = (...functionsToPipe) => {
  const finalPipeFunction = functionsToPipe.reduce(toASingleFunction, /* start with */ theIdentityFunction);

  return finalPipeFunction;
}

const f = pipe(
  x => x + 1,
  x => x * 2,
  x => x * x
);

console.log(f(2)) // ((2 + 1) * 2) ^ 2 === 36
```

Maybe this helps?

good luck!

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)