# Typescript recursive function composition

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, function-composition, spread-syntax

I want to create a function chain, which would be an input of a pipe/flow/compose function.

Is this possible without the literal expansion of the types to selected depth, as is this usually handled? [See lodash's flow](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/common/util.d.ts#L209).

I want to achieve typecheck of the data flow in the chain.
 - Argument of a function is result of the previous one
 - First argument is a template parameter
 - Last return is a template parameter

```typescript
type Chain<In, Out, Tmp1 = any, Tmp2 = any> = [] | [(arg: In) => Out] | [(arg: In) => Tmp1, (i: Tmp1) => Tmp2, ...Chain<Tmp2, Out>];
```

The idea is in the draft.

This however produces tho following errors:

1. `Type alias 'Chain' circularly references itself.` (understand why, don't know how to resole)
2. `A rest element type must be an array type.` (probably spread is not available for generic tuples)
3. `Type 'Chain' is not generic.` (don't even understand why this error is even here)

Is this definition of `Chain` possible in Typescript? If so, please enclose a snippet.

(Tested on latest tsc `3.1.6`)

Comment: Isn't this a "turtles all the way down" problem? i.e. it is impossible to resolve the recursive type.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Circular type aliases are not really supported except in certain cases. (UPDATE TS 4.1, these are more supported now, but I'm still inclined to represent `flow()` as operating on `AsChain`  that *verifies a particular* array of functions instead of trying to come up with a `Chain` that matches *all valid* arrays of functions)

Instead of trying to represent the specific type you've written there in a TypeScript-friendly way, I think I'll back up and interpret your question as: how can we type a `flow()`-like function, which takes as its arguments a variable number of one-argument functions, where each one-argument-function return type is the argument type for the next one-argument-function, like a chain... and which returns a one-argument function representing the collapsed chain?

I've got something that I believe works, but it's quite complicated, using a lot of [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types), [tuple spreads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types), and [mapped tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  Here it is:

```
type Lookup<T, K extends keyof any, Else=never> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : Else

type Tail<T extends any[]> = T extends [any, ...infer R] ? R : never;

type Func1 = (arg: any) => any;
type ArgType<F, Else=never> = F extends (arg: infer A) => any ? A : Else;
type AsChain<F extends [Func1, ...Func1[]], G extends Func1[]= Tail<F>> =
  { [K in keyof F]: (arg: ArgType<F[K]>) => ArgType<Lookup<G, K, any>, any> };

type Last<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer F, infer L] ? L : never;
type LaxReturnType<F> = F extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never;

declare function flow<F extends [(arg: any) => any, ...Array<(arg: any) => any>]>(
  ...f: F & AsChain<F>
): (arg: ArgType<F[0]>) => LaxReturnType<Last<F>>;
```

Let's see if it works:

```
const stringToString = flow(
  (x: string) => x.length, 
  (y: number) => y + "!"
); // okay
const str = stringToString("hey"); // it's a string

const tooFewParams = flow(); // error

const badChain = flow(
  (x: number)=>"string", 
  (y: string)=>false, 
  (z: number)=>"oops"
); // error, boolean not assignable to number
```

Looks good to me.

---

I'm not sure if it's worth it to go through in painstaking detail about how the type definitions work, but I might as well explain how to use them:

- `Lookup<T, K, Else>` tries to return `T[K]` if it can, otherwise it returns `Else`.  So `Lookup<{a: string}, "a", number>` is `string`, and `Lookup<{a: string}, "b", number>` is `number`.
- `Tail<T>` takes a tuple type `T` and returns a tuple with the first element removed.  So `Tail<["a","b","c"]>` is `["b","c"]`.
- `Func1` is just the type of a one-argument function.
- `ArgType<F, Else>` returns the argument type of `F` if it's a one-argument function, and `Else` otherwise.  So `ArgType<(x: string)=>number, boolean>` is `string`, and `ArgType<123, boolean>` is `boolean`.
- `AsChain<F>` takes a tuple of one-argument functions and tries to turn it into a chain, by replacing the return type of each function in `F` with the argument type of the next function (and using `any` for the last one).  If `AsChain<F>` is compatible with `F`, everything's good.  If `AsChain<F>` is incompatible with `F`, then `F` is not a good chain.  So, `AsChain<[(x: string)=>number, (y:number)=>boolean]>` is `[(x: string)=>number, (y: number)=>any]`, which is good.  But `AsChain<[(x: string)=>number, (y: string)=>boolean]>` is `[(x: string)=>string, (y: string)=>any]`, which is not good.
- `Last<T>` takes a tuple and returns the last element, which we need to represent the return type of `flow()`.  `Last<["a","b","c"]>` is `"c"`.
- Finally, `LaxReturnType<F>` is just like [`ReturnType<F>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) but without a constraint on `F`.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.2.3#code/PTAuE8AcFMAIGEAWBDAlgOwDwEl0BpYB5AV1AIBUBbSARlgF5Zl1wLqAmBplgPi4G0AurAA+sfgApkAJwDmALli4AlAz4lQwsZJkKl6VfT5VaBCakUmah4xwIA6R0jRYT7Ahp6CA3AChfEDCwADIA9qEA1sSQmOQEANKw0AAeoNDoACYAzrAR0OChAGbcrLAAogA2WXCM6NAAbtDSfIyJKWmZOXkFxeSwAPyw5PzxwoqV1QFQcORoFbFJqenZJUItQ4sdK-zMpY72GIVNsABKwoMnsIp1jdJ+gXAAYsToAMZ0jFJyirs2JffTWAAQTk5GmmEeBAmNVgNya60em2WOS+ekOxyBf12A2BV3KVWgAKCQKyzgwEKRnXEzzeNAcjhp7yEggIAHFKStGTQhFxZqh5o8eC1fLBYABvcSJDC5fJFWCPQSKVGKEGyMEwCEjQQ8P6q9XQTBhSLRTCshIEXY8C28WAAXz8UyCwWQWVAC3ayNW2t5HJy-H26Ok8oIgZC5xCeLhd38DxCyGSJ2goGI0nQ+ohCN9sAk+10WR+LD+ocuF0jDSaDoy0FeFRkcEKL1eoFQoXQsEKFVCAHcKR6qTpviUsSx6fYQdJkOBMMqh2oSl4eBIRbB9oVFIiAGTA0kocmC3zKJW6FWg8GPfgABm1f2dCaTKbT4OdrozPAdr1brtgrukGDVoQAZVAX90FkLgO27JdRQkZJFB-P8-mSewKnSWRQEQPBlwkcBrmISgACMmj+cBYAAalgAAiABCCiD28WAQFgSJJ18D90C-H8uHg0DyEA4C-wkCjEHyCjlHoxjUFAAByHJkG-fjQN8H97FAUIAFVIBgaR4BdaAJDE-w2K-VTQkeaAuwABRkZBKByRgIK7fTxOAJJpGkUJpEMz9QFgfDkAyMk23sztHKw2DYTwwjpD+CjuNkCjMOgnD5JA2Q-kKZACUS7MAC9cIIoi5wo8JICyWixIYlymnc6QCHw8IUOYWFQh8l0slQWR0GQfCUNgVSIoKzygA)

Comment: What you did here is pretty impressive. It works indeed. The only minor setback is that the error seems to be always on the first function, no matter where the chain breaks (though message is correct), which inherently seems to be the problem of the solution. You are validating the chain in AsChain, not defining the type. The main issue is obviously the complexity of the notation.

Why are recursive types not supported? Are they planned to be supported in following versions? The draft I provided, if supported, is brief, conscious, maintainable and easy to write.

Comment: "Are they planned to be supported"?  Read the "Recursive Types" design notes section here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27102

Comment: as for error always on the first function, yeah I noticed that.  I'm not sure that a recursive type would fare better on that front; it seems to be a bug in IntelliSense.  Maybe I'll report it.

Comment: Okay I [reported the error message issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28505) and it's apparently a bug.  Maybe it'll be fixed in TS3.3?

Comment: Ok, I went through the code, and I appriciate it even more. But I have found another issue: See this snippet (https://pastebin.com/FqxUXCit). The arguments are correctly validated, if you state all the types explicitly. However if you omit the types, the type from the previous function is not inferred. Again, I think this is the problem inherited from your "validation" solution, instead of "constructive" solution, via recursion (which is alas not supported in TS). Notice that all functions are `(_: any) => any`, types cannot be inferred this way. The result is only validated through `AsChain`.

Comment: Also (for further readers), `Tail` can be simplifed to avoid confusion with function types `type Tail<T extends any[]> = T extends [any, ...Array<infer U>] ? U[] : never;`. And `K extends keyof any` is redundant in `Lookup`

Comment: You cannot simplify `Tail` that way without losing the ordering.  `Tail<[1,2,3,4]>` should be `[2,3,4]`, not `Array<2 | 3 | 4>`.  Moreover, `Tail<Tail<[1,2,3,4]>>` should be `[3,4]`, not `never`.

Comment: I don't see how `K extends keyof any` is redundant; it's a constraint on the type of thing you can pass as `K` when calling `Lookup`.  You could remove the constraint if you like, but it means something slightly different... `Lookup<{}, {}>` would be a compile error in my version, and `never` in yours.

Comment: As for the issue with inferring types from previous functions, yeah, it's possible that *if* TypeScript supported recursive types, it would solve that problem, but there's no way to know right now.  Possibly there is a way to get your desired behavior without recursive types; the easiest would be to pick some maximum chain length and hardcode a non-recursive type.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293200/typescript-get-deeply-nested-property-value-using-array/53305221#53305221) for such a solution to a different problem.

Comment: You are right with the `Tail`, thank you for clarification. Same goes for `Lookup`, I did not realize `keyof any` ~ `string | number | symbol`.

Comment: doesn't work with generic function arguments unfortunately, as `ArgType` cannot retain and propagate the type parameter (inferred to `unknown`). E.g. `const asList = <T>(t: T) => [t] as [T]` in `stringToString`.

Comment: Wow this is cool! Do you know why this breaks now on TS 4.2.3? `Type 'Last<F>' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.`

Comment: @joshuaaron hmm, not sure, but I've fixed it by relaxing the constraint on `ReturnType` above.

Comment: @jcalz stupid question but with this just being a declaration function, how would the flow implementation look for this so it could be used in a ts/tsx file?

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7bPDw)?  An explanation is probably outside the scope of the question and not suitable for comments.

Comment: For a different question (closed as a duplicate of this one :-) I arrived upon this recursive solution: https://tsplay.dev/wQ5r1w The error messages are a bit more accurate, and the code is relatively easy to follow. If anyone is still interested in this topic, I can add it as a second answer to the question.