# Get deeply nested property value using array

Tags: typescript

I'd like to declare a function that can take an object plus an array of nested property keys and derive the type of the nested value as the return type of the function.

e.g.

```
const value = byPath({ state: State, path: ['one', 'two', 'three'] }); 
// return type == State['one']['two']['three']

const value2 = byPath({ state: State, path: ['one', 'two'] });
// return type == State['one']['two']
```

The best I've been able to put together is the following, but it is more verbose than I'd like it to be, and I have to add a function overload for every level of nesting.

```
export function byPath<
  K1 extends string,
  R
>({ state, path }: {
  state: {[P1 in K1]?: R},
  path: [K1]
}): R;

export function byPath<
  K1 extends string,
  K2 extends string,
  R
>({ state, path }: {
  state: {[P1 in K1]?: {[P2 in K2]?: R}},
  path: [K1, K2]
}): R;

export function byPath<
  K1 extends string,
  K2 extends string,
  K3 extends string,
  R
>({ state, path }: {
  state: {[P1 in K1]?: {[P2 in K2]?: {[P3 in K3]?: R}}},
  path: [K1, K2, K3]
}): R;

export function byPath<R>({ state, path }: { state: State, path: string[] }): R | undefined {
  // do the actual nested property retrieval
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this with fewer lines of code and without adding a function overload for every level of nesting?

Comment: I think this is an awesome question. Maybe it is possible to recursively traverse the path array during compile time by using spread types (`path: [KH, ...KT]`), but unfortunately this is [not supported in TS 3.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26113). Nevertheless, I tried to come up with an untested [POC](https://gist.github.com/flash1293/71ea45dad4035edd84f8713a272f1f16); Maybe it will work if TS supports rest types in tuples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NEW ANSWER FOR TypeScript 5.0+

Now that TypeScript supports [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) as well as, well a whole lot of new features, I'd probably write the code this way:

```
type DeepIdx<T, K extends readonly PropertyKey[]> =
    K extends readonly [
      infer K0 extends keyof T, 
      ...infer KR extends readonly PropertyKey[]
    ] ? DeepIdx<T[K0], KR> : T;

type DeepRecord<K extends readonly PropertyKey[], V> =
    K extends readonly [
      infer K0 extends PropertyKey, 
      ...infer KR extends readonly PropertyKey[]
   ] ? { [P in K0]: DeepRecord<KR, V> } : V;

declare function byPath<
  T extends DeepRecord<K, any>, 
  const K extends readonly PropertyKey[]
>({ state, path }: { state: T, path: K }): DeepIdx<T, K>;
```

which produces this behavior:

```
const State = { one: { two: { three: { four: 123 } } } };

const value = byPath({ state: State, path: ['one', 'two', 'three'] });
// const value: {four: number};
const oops = byPath({ state: State, path: ['one', 'too', 'three'] }); // error!
// -----------------> ~~~~~
// Property 'too' is missing in type '{ two: { three: { four: number; }; }; }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&jsx=0&ts=5.1.6#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIlKECSATAHgHgCoBoYDSMU6IUAdqgM4wBOUAhqgPbkA2YMACrc9LeAJQwAbQC6APhgBeYDHmFipCtTqMW7TiICW5AGZRahAAxKylGgGthzPTDwwAdM90GjBAEpmVNek1Yc3Lz8gsLiYjAA-HIKCEhoWNgiBMZi+J5SAFz2ANzAoJCwcRAeUADGzLSomEQk5qp+GoE8fIahomkwAGpSsgqKdT5q-powOvqGJt4WQa0CYEJg+M6OrpOe0w3qAZwtIQthYhHR-QDeY1wwuiZi2cWlFVU1Hvg9MAC+MNldecCo5WwGPQYHoAK7kMogbSsGAAIzAXAYIAAFjhNjR7uVKtUCPgGOQwBJ8BVyFQQANlDNGjtZvtFuIJAAKc5kpFQfAQJHIj6ZGLyFkgNnZByclHZIjvACUd0QKAwOHSEl+wBJZJgAGVBWQZDBzqwoNlziAAO7MQ0wFH0A26kHMUG0bIARgATABmD4ez7vX6q8kANwYbFBsGkcIRXOZMFZZGymrZHK52REAHJ9cn8MmTcx0zBM8ircmIlK8gB6EswX0wANB62nPR2h0wciggC2sMM3pVrDVzD4NFD8MRKMj0etcbICbFY1T5CgOczvfnlsQhY+kpyMDLxFovFoAEJgFuALQn09n88nqQAPxvN8P5b2bU4C+zVxoLe0VCougA5ldyBahS5kaprmsuta2va2TNm2hgbt6HzwcAQA)

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER for TypeScript 3.2:

Unfortunately, TypeScript doesn't currently allow arbitrary [recursive type functions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980), which is what you want to iterate through a list of keys, drill down into an object type, and come out with the type of the nested property corresponding to the list of keys.  You can do pieces of it, but it's a mess.

So you're going to have to pick some maximum level of nesting and write for that.  Here's a possible type signature for your function which doesn't use overloads:

```
type IfKey<T, K> = [K] extends [keyof T] ? T[K] : T;

declare function byPath<T0,
  K1 extends keyof T0 | undefined, T1 extends IfKey<T0, K1>,
  K2 extends keyof T1 | undefined, T2 extends IfKey<T1, K2>,
  K3 extends keyof T2 | undefined, T3 extends IfKey<T2, K3>,
  K4 extends keyof T3 | undefined, T4 extends IfKey<T3, K4>,
  K5 extends keyof T4 | undefined, T5 extends IfKey<T4, K5>,
  K6 extends keyof T5 | undefined, T6 extends IfKey<T5, K6>
>({ state, path }: { state: T0, path: [K1?, K2?, K3?, K4?, K5?, K6?] }): T6;
```

Note that you can easily extend that to more than six layers of nesting if you need to.

The way it works: there are two kinds of type parameters... key types (named `K1`, `K2`, etc), and object types (named `T0`, `T1`, etc).  The `state` property is of type `T0`, and the path is a [tuple with optional elements](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) of the key types.  Each key type is either a key of the previous object type, or it's `undefined`.  If the key is undefined, then the next object type is the same as the current object type; otherwise it's the type of the relevant property.  So as soon as key types become and stay `undefined`, the object types become and stay the last relevant property type... and the last object type (`T6` above) is the return type of the function.

Let's do an example: if `T0` is `{a: {b: string}, c: {d: string}}`, then `K1` must be one of `'a'`, `'d'`, or `undefined`.  Let's say that `K1` is `'a'`.  Then `T1` is `{b: string}`.  Now `K2` must be `'b'` or `undefined`.  Let's say that `K2` is `'b'`.  Then `T2` is `string`.  Now `K3` must be in `keyof string` or `undefined`.  (So `K3` could be `"charAt"`, or any of the `string` methods and properties).  Let's say that `K3` is `undefined`.  Then `T3` is `string` (since it is the same as `T2`).  And if all the rest of `K4`, `K5`, and `K6` are `undefined`, then `T4`, `T5`, and `T6` are just `string`.  And the function returns `T6`.

So if you do this call:

```
const ret = byPath({state: {a: {b: "hey"}, c: {d: "you"} }, path: ['a', 'b'] });
```

Then `T0` will be inferred as `{a: {b: string}, c: {d: string}`, `K1` will be `'a'`, `K2` will be `'b'`, and `K3` through `K6` will all be `undefined`.  Which is the example above, so `T6` will be `string`.  And thus `ret` will of type `string`.

The above function signature should also yell at you if you enter a bad key:

```
const whoops = byPath({ state: { a: { b: "hey" }, c: { d: "you" } }, path: ['a', 'B'] });
// error! type "B" is not assignable to "b" | undefined: ----------------------> ~~~
```

That error makes sense, since `B` is not valid.  The following also yells at you:

```
const alsoWhoops = byPath({ state: { a: { b: "hey" }, c: { d: "you" } }, path: ['A', 'b'] });
// error! type "A" is not assignable to "a" | "c" | undefined: ---------------> ~~~
// also error! Type "b" is not assignable to "a" | "c" | undefined ?! -------------> ~~~
```

The first error is exactly what you'd expect; the second is a little weird, since `"b"` is fine.  But the compiler now has no idea what to expect for `keyof T['A']`, so it is acting as if `K1` were `undefined`.  If you fix the first error, the second will go away.  There might be ways to alter the `byPath()` signature to avoid this, but it seems minor to me.

---

In case you care about that erroneous second error message you could use the slightly more complex:

```
type IfKey<T, K> = [K] extends [keyof T] ? T[K] : T
type NextKey<T, K = keyof any> = [K] extends [undefined] ? undefined :
  [keyof T | undefined] extends [K] ? keyof any : (keyof T | undefined)

declare function byPath<T0,
  K1 extends NextKey<T0>, T1 extends IfKey<T0, K1>,
  K2 extends NextKey<T1, K1>, T2 extends IfKey<T1, K2>,
  K3 extends NextKey<T2, K2>, T3 extends IfKey<T2, K3>,
  K4 extends NextKey<T3, K3>, T4 extends IfKey<T3, K4>,
  K5 extends NextKey<T4, K4>, T5 extends IfKey<T4, K5>,
  K6 extends NextKey<T5, K5>, T6 extends IfKey<T5, K6>
>({ state, path }: { state: T0, path: [K1?, K2?, K3?, K4?, K5?, K6?] }): T6;
```

which is pretty much the same except for when things go wrong with keys not matching what they're supposed to match.

Comment: Seems to not work on Partial<Record<T>> types. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: I ended up solving with 
type IfKey<T, K> = [K] extends [keyof T] ? Exclude<Required<T[K]>, undefined> : T;    and then return type of T6 extends Required<infer U> ? U : T6