# Defining a type-safe generic object accessor function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to write a type definition for a utility function like this:

```
function getter<T>(field1, field2?, field3?) {
    if (field3 !== undefined) {
        return (obj: T) => obj[field1][field2][field3];
    } else if (field2 !== undefined) {
        return (obj: T) => obj[field1][field2];
    } else {
        return (obj: T) => obj[field1];
    }
}
```

Such that, given the following interface:

```
interface Contact { phone: string; }
interface Author { name: string; contact: Contact; }
interface Book { id: number; author: Author; }
```

And example instance:

```
const lordOfTheRings: Book = { id: 1, author: { name: 'JRR Tolkien', contact: { phone: '222222' } } };
```

You could use `getter<Book>('author', 'name')` to get a function which, when called with the argument `lordOfTheRings`, would return `JRR Tolkien`.

So the function above works fine but it's not type safe. I want to be able to write `getter<Book>('id')` and have it compile happily but if I were to write `getter<Book>('banana')` have it give me a type error because `banana` isn't a valid key of `Book`. I just want this to work up to three levels deep.

I've been round and round on this and struggled to write a type definition that works in all edge cases.

What I can do is something like this:

```
interface Getter<T> {
    <K extends keyof T>(field1: K): (obj: T) => T[K];
    <K extends keyof T, L extends keyof T[K]>(field1: K, field2: L): (obj: T) => T[K][L];
    <K extends keyof T, L extends keyof T[K], M extends keyof T[K][L]>(field1: K, field2: L, field3: M): (obj: T) => T[K][L][M];
}

const bookGetter: Getter<Book> = getter;
```

Which I can use like so:

```
bookGetter('id')              // No error
bookGetter('title')           // Error
bookGetter('author')(lordOfTheRings).name; // No error
bookGetter('author', 'name'); // No error
bookGetter('author', 'age');  // Error
bookGetter('author', 'contact')(lordOfTheRings).phone;  // No error
bookGetter('author', 'contact')(lordOfTheRings).email;  // Error
bookGetter('author', 'contact', 'phone');  // No error
bookGetter('author', 'contact', 'email');  // Error
```

This is the perfect behaviour in terms of the compiler, but I'd like to be able to specify the type as a parameter to the getter, rather than having to define a particular instance of a getter like this.

I tried this signature to the function:

```
function getter<T,
                K extends keyof T = keyof T,
                L extends keyof T[K] = keyof T[K],
                M extends keyof T[K][L] = keyof T[K][L]>(field1: K, field2?: L, field3?: M) {
```

Which initially seemed promising but fails on the specification like so:

```
getter<Book>('id');    // No error - correct
getter<Book>('title'); // Error - correct
getter<Book>('author')(lordOfTheRings).name; // Error - NOT correct (property name does not exist on number | Author)
getter<Book>('author', 'name'); // All the rest also error in the same way as this one (argument of type not assignable to parameter of type never)
```

Please don't worry about the practical utility of this function - at this point it's become of of an intellectual exercise in type specification! Can we crack it?

[Click here to go to an example TS playground with these in](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Getter%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(field1%3A%20K)%3A%20(obj%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20T%5BK%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%20L%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK%5D%3E(field1%3A%20K%2C%20field2%3A%20L)%3A%20(obj%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20T%5BK%5D%5BL%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%20L%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK%5D%2C%20M%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK%5D%5BL%5D%3E(field1%3A%20K%2C%20field2%3A%20L%2C%20field3%3A%20M)%3A%20(obj%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20T%5BK%5D%5BL%5D%5BM%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20function%20getter%3CT%2C%20K%20extendIs%20infer%20F%20%3F%20F%20%3A%20keyof%20T%3E(field1%3A%20F)%3A%20(obj%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20T%5BF%5D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20function%20getter%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%20%3D%20keyof%20T%2C%20L%20extends%20Keys%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%20%3D%20Keys%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%3E(field1%3A%20K%2C%20field2%3A%20L)%3A%20(obj%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20T%5BK%5D%5BL%5D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20function%20getter%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%20%3D%20keyof%20T%2C%20L%20extends%20Keys%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%20%3D%20Keys%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%2C%0D%0A%2F%2F%20M%20extends%20Keys%3CT%5BK%5D%5BL%5D%3E%20%3D%20Keys%3CT%5BK%5D%5BL%5D%3E%3E(field1%3A%20K%2C%20field2%3A%20L%2C%20field3%3A%20M)%3A%20(obj%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20T%5BK%5D%5BL%5D%5BM%5D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20getter%3CT%2C%0D%0A%20%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%20%3D%20keyof%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20L%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK%5D%3D%20keyof%20T%5BK%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20M%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK%5D%5BL%5D%3D%20keyof%20T%5BK%5D%5BL%5D%3E(field1%3A%20K%2C%20field2%3F%3A%20L%2C%20field3%3F%3A%20M)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(field3%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(obj%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20obj%5Bfield1%5D%5Bfield2%5D%5Bfield3%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(field2%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(obj%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20obj%5Bfield1%5D%5Bfield2%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(obj%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20obj%5Bfield1%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20----%20Example%20Usage%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Contact%20%7B%20phone%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20Author%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%3B%20contact%3A%20Contact%3B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20Book%20%7B%20id%3A%20number%3B%20author%3A%20Author%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bookGetter%3A%20Getter%3CBook%3E%20%3D%20getter%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20lordOfTheRings%3A%20Book%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20id%3A%201%2C%20author%3A%20%7B%20name%3A%20'JRR%20Tolkien'%2C%20contact%3A%20%7B%20phone%3A%20'222222'%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Agetter%3CBook%3E('id')(lordOfTheRings).name%3B%0D%0Agetter%3CBook%3E('bones')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Agetter%3CBook%3E('id')%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20No%20error%20-%20correct%0D%0Agetter%3CBook%3E('title')%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%20-%20correct%0D%0Agetter%3CBook%3E('author')(lordOfTheRings).name%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%20-%20NOT%20correct%20(property%20name%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20number%20%7C%20Author)%0D%0Agetter%3CBook%3E('author'%2C%20'name')%3B%20%2F%2F%20All%20the%20rest%20also%20error%20(argument%20of%20type%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20never)%0D%0Agetter%3CBook%3E('author'%2C%20'age')%3B%0D%0Agetter%3CBook%3E('author'%2C%20'contact')(lordOfTheRings).phone%3B%0D%0Agetter%3CBook%3E('author'%2C%20'contact')(lordOfTheRings).email%3B%0D%0Agetter%3CBook%3E('author'%2C%20'contact'%2C%20'phone')%3B%0D%0Agetter%3CBook%3E('author'%2C%20'contact'%2C%20'email')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AbookGetter('id')%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20No%20error%0D%0AbookGetter('title')%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0AbookGetter('author')(lordOfTheRings).name%3B%20%2F%2F%20No%20error%0D%0AbookGetter('author'%2C%20'name')%3B%20%2F%2F%20No%20error%0D%0AbookGetter('author'%2C%20'age')%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0AbookGetter('author'%2C%20'contact')(lordOfTheRings).phone%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20No%20error%0D%0AbookGetter('author'%2C%20'contact')(lordOfTheRings).email%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0AbookGetter('author'%2C%20'contact'%2C%20'phone')%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20No%20error%0D%0AbookGetter('author'%2C%20'contact'%25).

Using TypeScript 3.1.4.

Comment: Why not avoid writing that function, and simply use `const getter = (b: Book) => book.author.name;`. This is typesafe, shorter and more readable, IMHO.

Comment: OK, I've now just read your practical utility note. Sorry for not noticing before.

Comment: I just can't help spending hours writing type definitions instead of useful code that does things. Everybody has their weakness.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: Get deeply nested property value using array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293200/typescript-get-deeply-nested-property-value-using-array)... with rest parameter instead of array, but the same idea

Comment: It's similar but not quite. For one in this case we are typing a factory for an accessor, not the object accessor itself.  In my experiments this has complicated things because TS can't resolve the parameter for the object itself.

Perhaps you answer from that question can be adapted (and that innovation of propagating the final resolved type may help) but I was not able to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in the way you define `getter` is that Typescript does not support partial argument inference. So when you say `getter<Book>` the rest of the type parameters will not be inferred, they will just use their default values. This means that `T[K]` will be a union of all property types of `T` and will probably not have any common keys, hence the error about `never` you have been getting.

Partial type inference is probably going to be added to Typescript in 3.3 (as per this [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349)) but even then you would have to write something like `getter<Book, *>` adding `*` for each type parameter you want inferred.

A solution that will work now (and IMO actually reads better) is to use function currying (ie a function that returns a function). With this approach you will specify the target type in the first call and let inference take care of the rest in the second call:

```
function getter<T>() {
  function makeGetter<K extends keyof T>(field1: K): (obj: T) => T[K];
  function makeGetter<K extends keyof T, L extends keyof T[K]>(field1: K, field2: L): (obj: T) => T[K][L];
  function makeGetter<K extends keyof T, L extends keyof T[K], M extends keyof T[K][L]>(field1: K, field2: L, field3: M): (obj: T) => T[K][L][M];
  function makeGetter(field1: keyof any, field2?: keyof any, field3?: keyof any) {
    if (field2 !== undefined && field3 !== undefined) {
      return (obj: any) => obj[field1][field2][field3];
    } else if (field2 !== undefined) {
      return (obj: any) => obj[field1][field2];
    } else {
      return (obj: any) => obj[field1];
    }
  }

  return makeGetter;
}

// ---- Example Usage

interface Contact { phone: string; }
interface Author { name: string; contact: Contact; }
interface Book { id: number; author: Author; }

const bookGetter: Getter<Book> = getter;

const lordOfTheRings: Book =
  { id: 1, author: { name: 'JRR Tolkien', contact: { phone: '222222' } } };

getter<Book>()('id')(lordOfTheRings).name;
getter<Book>()('bones');
getter<Book>()('id');    // No error - correct
getter<Book>()('title'); // Error - correct
getter<Book>()('author')(lordOfTheRings).name; //ok 
getter<Book>()('author', 'name'); // ok
getter<Book>()('author', 'age'); //error
getter<Book>()('author', 'contact')(lordOfTheRings).phone; // ok
getter<Book>()('author', 'contact')(lordOfTheRings).email; //error
getter<Book>()('author', 'contact', 'phone'); // ok 
getter<Book>()('author', 'contact', 'email'); //error
```