# Typescript: Remove entries from tuple type

Tags: typescript, tuples

not sure if this is possible, but I would like to be able to define a type that converts tuples like: `[number, string, undefined, number]` to `[number, string, number]` (ie filter out `undefined`).

I thought about something like this:

```
type FilterUndefined<T extends any[]> = {
    [i in keyof T]: T[i] extends undefined ? /* nothing? */ : T[i];
}
```

Sadly I am am pretty sure that there is no way to achieve this.

Comment: Tuples are immutable. So you would have to replace one with another. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296643/convert-tuple-to-list-and-back

Comment: t = (1, "a", {"key":"value"})
l = list(t)
l.remove("a")
t2 = tuple(l)
print("t", t, "\nt2",t2) yields 
t (1, 'a', {'key': 'value'})                                                                                                                              
t2 (1, {'key': 'value'})

Comment: @JGFMK I think you are writing about Python and values, while the question is about Typescript and *types*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### TS 4.1

Filter operations on tuples are now [officially](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#recursive-conditional-types) possible:

```
type FilterUndefined<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [] ? [] :
    T extends [infer H, ...infer R] ?
    H extends undefined ? FilterUndefined<R> : [H, ...FilterUndefined<R>] : T
```

Let's do some tests to check, that it is working as intended:

```
type T1 = FilterUndefined<[number, string, undefined, number]> 
// [number, string, number]
type T2 = FilterUndefined<[1, undefined, 2]> // [1, 2]
type T3 = FilterUndefined<[undefined, 2]> // [2]
type T4 = FilterUndefined<[2, undefined]> // [2]
type T5 = FilterUndefined<[undefined, undefined, 2]> // [2]
type T6 = FilterUndefined<[undefined]> // []
type T7 = FilterUndefined<[]> // []
```

### More infos

- [Recursive conditional types #40002](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002) (TS 4.1)
- [Variadic tuple types #39094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094) (TS 4.0)

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgVQHYBMIDM4YRYA8AKlBAB7LYDOUArhgNYYD2A7hgNoC6AfFAC8UclRpZ6fKAH4o0gFwAoKKtEVqEOvIK5UUABIAaKADpzu-QCVeslWoMaJ9JjnyEss2ImTpseAiJiK0EFeWMzc3gkVEw3QJIQ2zDSJSVQSFEARmFvGL94j2JuDAYAWwAjVBNaYBQCAHMTVwCPE1LK1AEoAHoe+Q6qlBq6xvbyod508GhSACZc6N841qDuLOb-dyITOe6++Q2oPenM0gBmRZ9YrYTilu2sXf3+7hOM2YAWK-yVx+K5ptCkQXvJ3jNRABWH7LW5FbgPBJA1ZPY6gt5TD6iABsMJuwJICLhIMEBz4p1mAHY8QUUcV0bwgA)

Comment: Nice job! Why do you use "T extends any[]" instead of "T extends unknown[]"?

Comment: It was shorter :-). `any` used as generic constraint doesn't really matter here compared to `unknown` (top type) - you won't lose type safety. The important part is, that `T` is limited to array types (`readonly any[]` would be even a tad better). Though your hint is still useful: If `ESLint`/linters complain about `any` usage, it can be safely replaced by `unknown` for `FilterUndefined`.

Comment: PS: updated answer to use `unknown`. Thanks again @FlavioVilante for the hint.

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the tuple labels after filtering?

Comment: IIRC, not possible, @NandinBorjigin. While there are cases where named tuple members are preserved (such as when concatenating tuple types), this is not the case here. The recursive conditional type here `infer`s the members and "reconstructs" the tuple, thus losing the information about names.

Answer (score 29):

Got it! But it need a lot of recursive magic:

```js
type PrependTuple<A, T extends Array<any>> =
  A extends undefined ? T : 
  (((a: A, ...b: T) => void) extends (...a: infer I) => void ? I : [])

type RemoveFirstFromTuple<T extends any[]> = 
  T['length'] extends 0 ? undefined :
  (((...b: T) => void) extends (a, ...b: infer I) => void ? I : [])

type FirstFromTuple<T extends any[]> =
  T['length'] extends 0 ? undefined : T[0]

type NumberToTuple<N extends number, L extends Array<any> = []> = {
  true: L;
  false: NumberToTuple<N, PrependTuple<1, L>>;
}[L['length'] extends N ? "true" : "false"];

type Decrease<I extends number> = RemoveFirstFromTuple<NumberToTuple<I>>['length']
type H = Decrease<4>

type Iter<N extends number, Items extends any[], L extends Array<any> = []> = {
  true: L;
  false: Iter<FirstFromTuple<Items> extends undefined ? Decrease<N> : N, RemoveFirstFromTuple<Items>, PrependTuple<FirstFromTuple<Items>, L>>;
}[L["length"] extends N ? "true" : "false"];

type FilterUndefined<T extends any[]> = Iter<T['length'], T>
type I = [number, string, undefined, number];
type R = FilterUndefined<I>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20PrependTuple%3CA%2C%20T%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20A%20extends%20undefined%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20%0D%0A%20%20(((a%3A%20A%2C%20...b%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20extends%20(...a%3A%20infer%20I)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3F%20I%20%3A%20%5B%5D)%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RemoveFirstFromTuple%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%0D%0A%20%20T%5B'length'%5D%20extends%200%20%3F%20undefined%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20(((...b%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20extends%20(a%2C%20...b%3A%20infer%20I)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3F%20I%20%3A%20%5B%5D)%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FirstFromTuple%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20T%5B'length'%5D%20extends%200%20%3F%20undefined%20%3A%20T%5B0%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20NumberToTuple%3CN%20extends%20number%2C%20L%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20true%3A%20L%3B%0D%0A%20%20false%3A%20NumberToTuple%3CN%2C%20PrependTuple%3C1%2C%20L%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%5BL%5B'length'%5D%20extends%20N%20%3F%20%22true%22%20%3A%20%22false%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Decrease%3CI%20extends%20number%3E%20%3D%20RemoveFirstFromTuple%3CNumberToTuple%3CI%3E%3E%5B'length'%5D%0D%0Atype%20H%20%3D%20Decrease%3C4%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Iter%3CN%20extends%20number%2C%20Items%20extends%20any%5B%5D%2C%20L%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20true%3A%20L%3B%0D%0A%20%20false%3A%20Iter%3CFirstFromTuple%3CItems%3E%20extends%20undefined%20%3F%20Decrease%3CN%3E%20%3A%20N%2C%20RemoveFirstFromTuple%3CItems%3E%2C%20PrependTuple%3CFirstFromTuple%3CItems%3E%2C%20L%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%5BL%5B%22length%22%5D%20extends%20N%20%3F%20%22true%22%20%3A%20%22false%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FilterUndefined%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20Iter%3CT%5B'length'%5D%2C%20T%3E%0D%0Atype%20I%20%3D%20%5Bnumber%2C%20string%2C%20undefined%2C%20number%5D%3B%0D%0Atype%20R%20%3D%20FilterUndefined%3CI%3E%0D%0A)

How it works:

PrependToTuple is util that takes item `A` and list `T` and add it on first place when `A` is not undefined. `PrependToTuple<undefined, []> => []`, `PrependToTuple<undefined, [number]> => [number]`

`RemoveFirstFromTuple` works pretty mach i the same way

`NumberToTuple` is recursively check if length of final Tuple is `N`, if 
 not he add 1 to recursive call. This util is needed to create `Decrease` util.

And the most important z `Iter` works like recursive loop, when length of final tuple is `N` (size of `Input`) its return `Output`, but `PrependToTuple` is not increasing length when we try do add `undefined`, so when `Iter<FirstFromTuple<Items> extends undefined` we have to decrease N.

Comment: Good job! If I recall correctly `NumberToTuple` is a recursive type (from jcalz?) and has a max number of [23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54246826/9259778) after that it will give weird results. However tuples are rarely that long.

Comment: Yes for long tuples will throw error `'false' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.`

Comment: Where did you take all these types from? If it's not a secret :) I doubt you came up with them yourself?

Comment: No it's not secret. Trick with recursive tuple I got from react days 2018 in Verona. From lighting talk made by @MattiaManzati. I using this tricks in some extraordinary TS problems. Types like Iter was inspired by it

Comment: Yeah, this black magic does work. But sadly I can't use it to achieve the types I want to have, with such generic types the compiler just gives up and puts implicit anys everywhere interesting,

Answer (score 8):

Supplementary answer:

An extension of the approach in [ford04's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64034671/11407695) allows us to create a "splicer" utility type that can remove values at arbitrary indices (in case someone finds this in search of a solution to type-safe `splice`).

This involves creating a utility type that will generate the tuple with `undefined` from a given tuple and index:

```ts
type UndefIndex<T extends any[], I extends number> = {
    [ P in keyof T ] : P extends Exclude<keyof T, keyof any[]> ? P extends `${I}` ? undefined : T[P] : T[P]
}
```

Then this is just a matter of composing the `UndefIndex` and `FilterUndefined` types:

```
type FilterUndefined<T extends any[]> = T extends [] ? [] :
    T extends [infer H, ...infer R] ?
    H extends undefined ? FilterUndefined<R> : [H, ...FilterUndefined<R>] : T;

type SpliceTuple<T extends any[], I extends number> = FilterUndefined<UndefIndex<T, I>>;

type a = SpliceTuple<[1,2,3], 0>; //[2,3]
type b = SpliceTuple<[1,2,3], 1>; //[1,3]
type c = SpliceTuple<[1,2,3], 2>; //[1,2]
type d = SpliceTuple<[1,2,3], 3>; //[1,2,3]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgEwgMwJKIgDwDwBUpbASIDOUAhnCANoC6ANFKgZkaVHAK4C2ARhACcAfFAC8UAN4BYAFBR5UalAAKUAJZwoAawggA9sij5aUAFwqWbBGQCimAMYAbTkmw79h3I3cGKVOiIA-BaExNZQAAYAJBKoAL4RUMGcGMgaEAhmRtTKJua4ObSycbKyoJBQAMpgjmr2ELicNRB4lmFklDQMTG3sXHyCIuIAYmqORALwSGlwGdhTKOhIOF5MQkIA3KUy5dCj44ILM3P4oeydAWJGveF0SYp5sgrXZ7cayIJQABKMAHT-70%20ACUTIEngovjcyClpulMsF9hMjnDsECROZqD8oP9fojDqkUWi8kYtjIyuBoOQrtVavVGs1sNQAIz0ABM9AAzN0AAybKAAen51HZXPJFV41JqdQaTUcLWZbM53SZfMFCtFOwpUHsktpMoZCpF3VZqqFLNZRU1FUy4hp0vpcsZ5qVjA5psNSqAA)

Answer (score 0):

//  remove from tuple another tuple bu recursive

```
export type RemoveFromTuple<T extends unknown[], U extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer A, ...infer B] ? ( A extends U[number] ? RemoveFromTuple<B, U> : [A, ...RemoveFromTuple<B, U>]) : [];
```