# Obtain a "slice" of a Typescript 'Parameters' tuple

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the `Parameters` utility type, the underlying type of which is a tuple: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype

I have a function `SomeFunction`. To use the function's arguments as a type, I write `Parameters<SomeFunction>`.

Now let's say I want to use the function's arguments as a type *except for the first argument*.

Obviously for an array I would use something like `...args.slice(1)`. But I'm not aware of a slicing utility for Typescript definitions. `Omit` only works for objects.

[An answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54607819/2053389) provides a `RemoveFirstFromTuple` utility. But it's a bit convoluted. Is there a built-in way of extracting part of a tuple within a type definition?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, you can use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) on the function type, in a way very similar to how [the `Parameters` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) [is implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/87c5b6a752f8ac3239ac05fbcbbb889dc7c0019d/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1523-L1526):

```
type ParametersExceptFirst<F> = 
   F extends (arg0: any, ...rest: infer R) => any ? R : never;
```

compare to

```
// from lib.es5.d.ts
type Parameters<T extends (...args: any) => any> = 
  T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
```

and verify that it works:

```
declare function foo(x: string, y: number, z: boolean): Date;
type FooParamsExceptFirst = ParametersExceptFirst<typeof foo>;
// type FooParamsExceptFirst = [y: number, z: boolean]
declare function foo(x: string, y: number, z: boolean): Date;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBACgQwE4ILZRFJBnAogDwGMoIQAxASxxAB4yA+GAXhjJin0wDsATbGABTIA5gAYAXDARcwAGhgA6JUijYQkilwBmWGACUAlM0bSwMAPz6YkrlABuWANzBgPKIQA2yWFoCuXQhAKAHsuGC1g4IF8STUkTWF5MBtfVAAjLHkAL0k0yI8oaQNJABEETGdwaFZIxBRUPCIScio1ZnhkNAwsRuJSSmoaKqhgrXDI+mcAeimYYZrgurRe5oG2lgBtZJguVIykbNz8wq4AXSA)

---

**UPDATE:** arbitrary slicing of tuples with numeric literals is possible, but not pretty and has caveats.  First let's write `TupleSplit<T, N>` which takes a tuple `T` and a numeric [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) type `N`, and splits the tuple `T` at index `N`, returning two pieces: the first piece is the first `N` elements of `T`, and the second piece is everything after that.  (If `N` is more than the length of `T` then the first piece is all of `T` and the second piece is empty):

```
type TupleSplit<T, N extends number, O extends readonly any[] = readonly []> =
    O['length'] extends N ? [O, T] : T extends readonly [infer F, ...infer R] ?
    TupleSplit<readonly [...R], N, readonly [...O, F]> : [O, T]
```

This works via [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) on [variadic tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) and is therefore more computationally intensive than the relatively simple `ParametersExceptFirst` implementation above.  If you try this on long tuples (lengths more than 25 or so) you can expect to see recursion errors.  If you try this on ill-behaved types like non-fixed-length tuples or unions of things, you might get weird results.  It's fragile; be careful with it.

Let's verify that it works:

```
type Test = TupleSplit<readonly ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], 3>
// type Test = [readonly ["a", "b", "c"], readonly ["d", "e"]]
```

Looks good.

---

Now we can use `TupleSplit<T, N>` to implement `TakeFirst<T, N>`, returning just the first `N` elements of `T`, and `SkipFirst<T, N>`, which skips the first `N` elements of `T`:

```
type TakeFirst<T extends readonly any[], N extends number> =
    TupleSplit<T, N>[0];

type SkipFirst<T extends readonly any[], N extends number> =
    TupleSplit<T, N>[1];
```

And finally `TupleSlice<T, S, E>` produces the slice of tuple `T` from start position `S` to end position `E` (remember, slices are inclusive of the start index, and exclusive of the end index) by taking the first `E` elements of `T` and skipping the first `S` elements of the result:

```
type TupleSlice<T extends readonly any[], S extends number, E extends number> =
    SkipFirst<TakeFirst<T, E>, S>
```

---

To demonstrate that this more or less represents what array `slice()` does, let's write a function and test it:

```
function slice<T extends readonly any[], S extends number, E extends number>(
    arr: readonly [...T], start: S, end: E
) {
    return arr.slice(start, end) as readonly any[] as TupleSlice<T, S, E>;
}

const tuple = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] as const
// const tuple: readonly ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

const ret0 = slice(tuple, 2, 4);
// const ret0: readonly ["c", "d"]
console.log(ret0); // ["c", "d"]

const ret1 = slice(tuple, 0, 9);
// const ret1: readonly ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
console.log(ret1); // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

const ret2 = slice(tuple, 5, 3);
// const ret2: readonly []
console.log(ret2); // [];
```

This looks good; the returned arrays from `slice()` have types that accurately represent their values.

Of course, there are many caveats; if you pass negative or non-whole numbers to `slice()` for `S` and `E`, then `TupleSlice<T, S, E>` is very likely not to correspond to what actually happens with array slices: negative "from end" behavior is possibly implementable but it would be even uglier; non-whole numbers or even just `number` have not been tested but I expect recursion warnings and other things that go bump in the night.  Be warned!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAykglsAPDANFAOSggA9gIA7AEwGcoK4BbAIwgCd8B5Ysy2qNhACGVAPYVEIKEIogA2gF0oAXgHCxEqYoB8KgFBRDUTnIDkyCgHNgAC1NLS5anSIB+KHM74YSgFyweJ35BEXFJD3QKADN2KAAxfAA6ZMiYtigAJSVXAyN4JFQMbBCNcLlkxKz8AnwSsK0Kr3iFXX9PbwU9PVBIWAgaYBVYBGQ0REwsOs0PACIhGfwZ5gWoGYBjFZmqTYgZhXwAZm09AHoTqB7oGH7B1TkpsrnN5cWN-bVQ6bktnb3O7vAVyEAGsIHF0GwBjhAnw6A8pDJ5O8iI5YfQmKw2LplLlDPlRkUcNVtHIAAwKADcXUuUBQwPQYHBkOwMBhzg+pQRskU1TZ-AYLHY2NxwwKYwmeEIJIAjJTqYDRaNxmsINDUez4dJue8UHy6ALMfgAKJ69GCrH6Iy0+mMiFQmAgsF2lnG7T4FDHPRROAUNbAdDiKA0ZWq1nq4LqepapHu00G9jGuMYoUAChFQjYbH8mvKyR8+AGGeA-hQ+D4-iNegAlFAAN4iwTAOBsCjSTOJYPoFUpwtsYBl6g1oRwyPTRGKaR0fGoENE2muqkAXy6a3EAwuI2gdyeixeqw2i22i12SmHUFXFAGp3OF-XTYK2dHj3mu82B9WR9WJ5Xa8GjdJQydt297IPgABM+AACxVlSZznr+ajAKSj6fI874-J0t6iMgiSIKIlgpv+MFQHB3zods-y3n+EDANKgEhimIEQPgpL4AAnDB17wZe1G0ShnKzC+qx7usmyfjM35YTheEEY20rEaRO7CW+Ym-HKehUYhYH0V2ECMZu+AAKyHJxcGaY2YH8VGigaWu2EQLh+GETRYEKecihUl0ZlCAAbsIwA0CWWpUFAJo2CIUCsMA5DpKw9DiAAtBQECWEI-p+VAADuNj2WamJ0MgNB0LYMhtqIPohWBhlQKI6Q0KI+C1VAIDlVl6CIIgQYQNA6BFXA-R6EAA)

Comment: How to add a generic for the added parameter, and make it accord with the target function?

Comment: Comments on previously answered questions aren't a great place to ask followup questions.  You might want to open your own post along with a [mre] that demonstrates the issue you're facing.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

@jcalz accepted solution here has a limitation: it drops tuple labels:

```js
type OriginalTupleSplit = TupleSplit<[a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5], 2> 
// [[1, 2], [c: 3, d: 4, e: 5]]
```

Below is a modified version that doesn't do that:

```js
type TupleSplitHead<T extends any[], N extends number> = T['length'] extends N
  ? T
  : T extends [...infer R, any]
  ? TupleSplitHead<R, N>
  : never

type TupleSplitTail<T, N extends number, O extends any[] = []> = O['length'] extends N
  ? T
  : T extends [infer F, ...infer R]
  ? TupleSplitTail<[...R], N, [...O, F]>
  : never

type TupleSplit<T extends any[], N extends number> = [TupleSplitHead<T, N>, TupleSplitTail<T, N>]

type ModifiedTupleSplit = TupleSplit<[a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5], 2>
// [[a: 1, b: 2], [c: 3, d: 4, e: 5]]
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

This is less performant than @jcalz's solution - as it iterates the array twice, but it keeps the labels.