# How to specify single optional parameter value when calling a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function:

```
function myFunc(
  id: string,
  optionalParamOne?: number,
  optionalParamTwo?: string
) {
  console.log(optionalParamTwo);
}
```

I would like to call this function by specifying the `id` as it is required and `optionalParamTwo`. I don't care about `optionalParamOne`. I cannot change this function.

How can I call this function with the parameters `id` and `optionalParamTwo` without having to specify `optionalParamOne`?

I could do this:

`myFunc('abc', null, 'dog')`

But I have many optional parameters in my function signature and I'd rather not specify a value for each.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pfvdgp?file=index.ts)

Comment: I mentioned in my question _I cannot change this function_

Comment: If you can't change the function, then you have to pass `undefined` for all the optional values. Dont think there is a work around as we are limited to just calling the function

Comment: If you cannot change the function, then I am afraid that you'll have to pass `undefined` or `null` to every parameter. Next time consider using an `object` parameter when there's 3 or more params, that way you won't have to care about the order.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518615/skip-arguments-in-a-javascript-function answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You must provide some value (even if its `undefined`) for every ordered parameter before you can provide a value for a higher-indexed parameter.

The common pattern for reducing boilerplate when invoking functions with uninteresting parameters is to [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwUQCgLABQiiMAJgFyIDOUATjGAOYA0hxcADrAgIYA2ABR60eyAPJgApgH5KYEMgBGk2qyKJO3MPyEjkAFQDucWdToNGhAJSIA3m0QQEVOH0kA6PnEY5N8bYLCokZwVgDchAC+hIQA9LGIAMK0kjxQkog8iBxByJLptAC0kgAeOWCkFoigkFrkhE5gNCiouqJUiAC8uGSUNPRMzBpc-jq5Iab9FjadAHyIANpkQ+CkksAMkqRDfryBeiEAupkdjTQRBPHE1ze3d-cPj0+PAHpv7+9xCQCSkHwga0Qq3Wm1I1TgtEQUAAFhkcnoOqg4CBEKQEAByKCIQw8MBYqBwKHQhgAa0yimRWMMsKQEH4fCqMIyNWg-hiBDQmEgOHcvLQbWQVBw6J4igg6KG6LRjHRVnCiCuXkYHQARNKVeyrmJIQArEDNCAgWi0VAkKD1AhnLGcrAAdRgMPQkkMKgFHW6+HUvTMAxYDl2AQFEz65kG1i68xt3OWQIqIKk22GWjGB2M4XZUYg9sdztduSFIrFEsQ6LpUFlYQVCSVqrLGoIQA)

```ts
function myFunc (
  id: string,
  optionalParamOne?: number,
  optionalParamTwo?: string
) {
  console.log(optionalParamTwo);
}

// Create a parameter-expanding function:
const myParams = (id: string, optionalParamTwo?: string) => [id, undefined, optionalParamTwo] as const;
//                                                               ^^^^^^^^^
// Include undefined for the params you don't want to think about when calling the function

myFunc(...myParams('abc', 'dog')); // logs "dog"

// Or just curry it:
const myFuncWithFewerParams = (
  id: string,
  optionalParamTwo?: string,
) => myFunc(id, undefined, optionalParamTwo);

myFuncWithFewerParams('abc', 'cat'); // logs "cat"
```

For sliced tuples (addressing partial parameters) in the type system, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67605309/438273).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do so without changing the function. You can write a wrapper around this function with destructuring assignment like so to achieve the desired result:

```js
function myFunc(
  id: string,
  optionalParamOne?: number,
  optionalParamTwo?: string
) {
  console.log(optionalParamTwo);
}

interface MyFuncParams {
  optionalParamOne?: number,
  optionalParamTwo?: string
}

function myFuncWrapper(id: string, { optionalParamOne, optionalParamTwo }: MyFuncParams = {}) {
  myFunc(id, optionalParamOne, optionalParamTwo);
}

myFuncWrapper('abc', { optionalParamTwo: 'dog' });
```