# How can I avoid constructor boilerplate with an object-literal TypeScript class constructor?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript has convenient ["parameter property"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) shorthand for class constructors so that I don't have to explicitly define every property, like this:

```
class Pizza {
  constructor(
    private sauce: string,
    private cheese: string,
    public radius: number
  ) {}
}
```

However, I can also use a constructor that takes an object rather than an argument list (essentially, keyword arguments):

```
const pizza = new Pizza({sauce: 'marinara', cheese: 'Venezuelan Beaver', radius: 8})
```

This syntax has a number of conveniences, not least of which is the ability to use the spread operator to easily copy objects:

```
const anotherPizza = new Pizza({...pizza, radius: 10})
```

But unfortunately it means I can't use the constructor shortcut to avoid all the boilerplate (I think):

```
class Pizza {

  private sauce: string;
  private cheese: string;
  private radius: number;

  constructor({sauce, cheese, radius}: {
      sauce: string,
      cheese: string,
      radius: number
  }) {
    this.sauce = sauce;
    this.cheese = cheese;
    this.radius = radius;
  }
}
```

Is there some way to use an object-literal constructor like this and still avoid assigning every property explicitly?

Comment: No. The closest you could get is spreading an _array_ (or _tuple_, type-wise) of values.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you show a brief example of that? I'm still not sure how I can use the parameter property syntax with an array argument.

Comment: It wouldn't change the class definition or parameter property syntax _at all_, the point is you'd spread an array e.g. `['marinara', 'Venezuelan Beaver', 8]` to it, instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to what you're looking for is to get a tuple of constructor arguments using the relevant [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype). You can then create an *array* of parameter arguments and spread them (type-safely) to the constructor:

```js
class Pizza {
  constructor(
    private sauce: string,
    private cheese: string,
    public radius: number
  ) {}
}

type PizzaSpec = ConstructorParameters<typeof Pizza>;

const spec: PizzaSpec = ["marinara", "Venezuelan Beaver", 8];

const pizza = new Pizza(...spec);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mM11dm)

Although you can't use an object with property keys, the type you get is a [labeled tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements), equivalent to writing:

```js
const spec: [sauce: string, cheese: string, radius: number] = ...;
```

so you do get a little more documentation than just `[string, string, number]`.

Copying is much more limited, though; dealing with array slices in a type-safe way is [pretty complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67605309/3001761).