# how to remove an element from a type that is an array

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to remove one of the elements from a type that is an array? I'm looking to curry something and make the whole thing easier.

E.g.

```
function NEW_PERSON (name : string, age : number, weight : number, height : number) {

}

function CURRIED_NEW_PERSON (name : string) {
    return function (...args : Parameters<typeof NEW_PERSON>) { // remove index 0
        return NEW_PERSON(name, ...args); // error due to 5 arguments instead of 4
    }
}
```

How do I remove index 0 from `Parameters<typeof NEW_PERSON>`?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a utility type which extracts every element except the first one from a tuple using `infer`.

```
type ExceptFirst<T extends any[]> = 
  Parameters<typeof NEW_PERSON> extends [any, ...infer REST] 
    ? REST 
    : never

function CURRIED_NEW_PERSON (name : string) {
    return function (...args : ExceptFirst<Parameters<typeof NEW_PERSON>>) {
        return NEW_PERSON(name, ...args);
    }
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAOQKIHUD6AFVAlAZQHllEAKMAQwFsBTRALkQGcoAnGMAcwBpFKu9JmBDUARrTZ8A7rRhcAFlEaIR4yXwVzFy4aIlsAlIgDeAKDMBfC1ACeAB3qoAHhFr2oAMRhtWAHgAVRFpnKFowABNmfjBbAG0AXQA+RABeRDNERGxKNhpaMN8-O0c4YBQMHHxiZBSQsMjouMpYvgA6Ds5gSUQ8VAIAhIysrIB+Xv6gzJHhWgA3SQtQSFgERABhAFU8PABJVAARTDQsXEIScio6FVYObmNzEcQ2ApA2JGXoeCQyDrbcrjRJguNweby+KB+HJ5OiFZjFBy0MoVU7VEhJJIPaZPLIvKBvJAnKrnZAUfLtDoA5iGADc2MQ1ksQA)

Comment: I was wondering if this is what the OP wanted, because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67605309/13258211) describes it in detail.