# Remove first type of ConstructorParameters

Tags: typescript

I have a class `Foo` and I can obtain the types of its constructor parameters with `ConstructorParameters<typeof Foo>`.

These parameters are returned as a tuple, say `[number, string, string | undefined]`. Is it possible to remove the first type from this tuple? I.e. I want the resulting tuple to be `[string, string | undefined]`.

Please note that this must work with any amount of parameters greater than or equal to one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Remove entries from tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54607400/typescript-remove-entries-from-tuple-type)

Comment: Take a look at the `RemoveFirstFromTuple` type from [Przemyslaw Jan Beigert's answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54607819/732284). If `type T = [number, string, string | undefined]` and `type F = RemoveFirstFromTuple<T>`, then `F` becomes `[string, string | undefined]`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers provided by rid, I have constructed the following type, which in my opinion is a bit easier to read than the types provided in his/her answer:

```js
type RemoveFirst<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer H, ...infer R] ? R : T;
```

Comment: Nice. And it works when `T` is an empty tuple as well, in which case Przemyslaw Jan Beigert's answer returned `undefined`.