# TypeScript 3.7 recursive type gives "type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite"

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I'm trying to code a variadic `pipe` function which composes an arbitrary number of one-argument pure functions.
This typing should check that the return type of one function is the argument type of the next and so on.

I would expect this to work in TypeScript 3.7 which introduces recursive types but somehow it doesn't work and gives the error:

`TS2589: type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite`

Here's my code:

```
type Tail<T extends any[]> = ((...t: T) => void) extends ((x: any, ...u: infer U) => void) ? U : never;

type Pipe<FNS extends unknown[]> = FNS extends [(a: infer A) => infer B, (b: infer B) => infer C] ? C :
                                 FNS extends [(a: infer A) => infer B, (b: infer B) => infer C, Pipe<[...Tail<FNS>[]]>] ? C : never;
```

The `FNS` type represents the array of pure functions and the `Tail` type should make sure that only the tail of this array is returned, but still the compiler marks this as an infinite loop.

Usage example:

```
const numToString = (n: number): string => n.toString();
const toUpper = (s: string): string => s.toUpperCase();

// this works, Foo evaluates to string
type Foo = Pipe<[typeof numToString, typeof toUpper]>;

// this doesn't work, Foo is not evaluated
type Foo = Pipe<[typeof numToString, typeof toUpper, typeof toUpper]>;
```

The error is on this part:

```
Pipe<[...Tail<FNS>[]]>
```

Why is this infinite? What am I missing?

Comment: I manages to get rid of the error by changing the definition of `Pipe` to this:


`type Pipe<FNS extends unknown[]> = FNS extends [(a: infer A) => infer B, (b: infer B) => infer C] ? C :
                                 FNS extends [(a: infer A) => infer B, (b: infer B) => infer C, Pipe<Tail<FNS>>] ? C : never;`

but this evaluates to `never` instead of `string` so it's not correctly typed:
`type Foo = Pipe<[typeof numToString, typeof toUpper, typeof toUpper]>;`

Comment: TypeScript 3.7 is beta. I'm not saying that's the reason but why are you using a version that isn't yet officially out? For testing purposes?

Comment: I have not tried to reproduce the error myself but if it is a bug, let the devs know about it.

Comment: @jperl yes for testing purposes

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173203/typescript-recursive-function-composition)...

Answer (score 1):

Variadic types are on the future [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) and not part of 3.7.

This a highly anticipated feature that will really enable functional programming in

Typescript https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453