# Type tuple so that function chain has valid parameter and return types

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples

I'd like to create a type for this tuple / array below.

Where this is valid:

```
const funcs = [(a: string) => 1, (a: number) => 'A', (a: string) => 2]
```

And this is invalid:

```
const funcs = [(a: string) => 1, (a: number) => 2, (a: string) => 3]
```

The difference being the return type for the middle function changed from string to number.

Is it possible?

```
type SubtractOne<T extends number> = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62][T];
type AddOne<T extends number> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62][T];

const funcs = [(a: string) => 1, (a: number) => 'A', (a: string) => 2]

type CheckFuncs<T extends any[]> = { [(K extends number) in keyof T]: T[AddOne<K>] }

type funcsType = typeof funcs
type funcsType2 = CheckFuncs<funcsType>
```

During my research I came across a way to index with a mapping. Is it possible to use this to add or subtract `AddOne` to K? then I can access the `ReturnType` of `T[K]` and the `Parameter<T[k+1]>[0]`?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=5&ssl=10&ssc=40&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgI2AJwIYGNgHkB2EA8AKlBAB7AQ4AmAzlDnALYITIB8UAvFANoC0ARgA0UAAwjhUAEwiAzCIAsIgKwiAbCIDsIgBwiAnBPFQBkgTJPyTSk6pMaT2k3pOHpxqZKkWpVqTak7KQcpJykXKTdZY1lJWQtZK1kbWTtZB1knWRdZNwVjBUkFCwUrBRsFOwUHBScFFwU3ZWNlSWULZStlG2U7ZQdlJ2UXZTc1YzVJNSkAXR5CGYBuAFgAKFBIKABBKipcAmIyCmo6BmZWDm4eLzlFFXUtXQMjCTMLASsBGwE7AQcBJwCFwCNxSDxeHx+AJBEJhCJRGJxBJJFJpDJZHJ5ApFEplCpVGp1BpNFptDpdHp9AZDEZjCZTWbzJZrNboAD2OBowCgYFQNDoVwAFKgAFxQLnIACWOAA5gBKLgcSTCsVnFjIBWcDgAci22pEKvFKGl8sV0hmrI5XKgADNUJKADZcXiGiUmzVKg2i+hMdUeqBWV3G2X+2Ys9bgaAAYQAFhB0ABrABicBw6BoRBI5EotCgqBwIB4M0uUAA3rwANJQaVQBMQEBsm1QBZiqtHHOnX2sKAAfigACUIMA4MgcIRI0QeBXi1njrmAAqoNCMIesDOEHg7PZ4fAVtjFniiGa95tT4+qiAAN27F+vyCgAF9wxtoLz+ePNtxY-Hk6n0-gX0bHk+RoNg1hfW17QdD9oC-ONExTNMM0Aps7UdNggA)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript recursive function composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173203/typescript-recursive-function-composition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexing into the next or previous value of a tuple given an index type `K` is something I'd do with the support for [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types).  Consider `Tail<T>`, which takes a tuple type `T` and returns a new tuple type with the first element removed:

```
// Tail<[1,2,3]> is [2,3]
type Tail<T extends readonly any[]> = T extends [any, ...infer R] ? R : never;
```

Then "`T[K+1]`" can be expressed as `Tail<T>[K]` instead.

That's probably the answer to your question as asked, but I'll continue a little to show how to use it:

---

Here's how I might start writing your `CheckFuncs` type:

```
type CheckFuncs<T extends readonly ((x: any) => any)[]> = { [K in keyof T]:
    K extends keyof Tail<T> ? (
        [T[K], Tail<T>[K]] extends [(x: infer A) => infer R, (x: infer S) => any] ? (
            [R] extends [S] ? T[K] : (x: A) => S
        ) : never
    ) : T[K]
}
```

That walks through `T` and compares `T[K]` with `Tail<T>[K]`, and converts `T[K]` into a version of itself that works.  Then these (note that you need [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) for the tuple type to be preserved):

```
const pass = [(a: string) => 1, (a: number) => 'A', (a: string) => 2] as const
const fail = [(a: string) => 1, (a: number) => 3, (a: string) => 2] as const
```

produce these:

```
type passType = CheckFuncs<typeof pass>
// readonly [(a: string) => number, (a: number) => string, (a: string) => number]

type failType = CheckFuncs<typeof fail>
// readonly [(a: string) => number, (x: number) => string, (a: string) => number]
```

And you can make a function that works with `CheckFuncs` like this:

```
function useFuncs<T extends readonly ((x: any) => any)[]>(...t: CheckFuncs<T>) { }

useFuncs((a: string) => 1, (a: number) => 'A', (a: string) => 2); // okay
useFuncs((a: string) => 1, (a: number) => 3, (a: string) => 2); // error!
// ----------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '(a: number) => number' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '(x: number) => string'.
```

Of course the exact way you want to write or use `CheckFuncs` might be different; this is just an illustration.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgSwDYB4ZQgD2BAdgEwGcoAnCOfAe1yRCjlxAG0BdAPigF5YNs8ioTBiAA0UAHSSEuAGYQSUAEosoAfiVQAXFFwQAbvIDcAWABQZ0JCgBhABYQAxgGsAYgFdcDwml44CxMgpqWigAClDMbWEASi4OGNYObgBvQQBpKGkoJwgQShlYFk0zKFKoDKw-ARy8gvhkNA51UJKytqYYJjSWMXrUGDYulhVK-mImCO1pOQUAQVjODmn5JTFJzNkVgGUF+MYVZta248FlXzHBLYPYIa0wyKh5uKgto+PY7V0DEjePm+6zABfMxmBzUQjAKBgOCEYjcCZwbQQkjSADmuygAEY1oidG4ALYAI3kGIA5LNSTikcAUbh0c8AEwqGFQMG4CGg8GQmSIJBcQShXHItEY7FhXG4AnEkgYgDMVKgwrpGKZ9GIbI55lMlmg0NhMHA0G4dkcrg8XhQOvyUJhhDYZgA9A7SOQqDQ6AjqbT6Ys8UT5ArJf6Zc8laiFWGMUHpSwQdrDVAecgDVZjfZnO5PN4rQUk0h7aYnS6gu6BUKaSLntGA-dPlKSaGK3SI02fRxqyRY1qZObgAhqFA3IQIJmLehRv5i26QuEHjFngl2KFJOJgNoTRnzd4BrFUsCtUOR1vwuXvaLA-WQ77yZTxV7K76GdFDFAi5QnHAQGZD6PCCf78qzxioKdbBnKLZnoyz6vs68gkJQJAAISOs6AC06EYZhWHYahHAAH4EYRRHEXhKGPCQqIEngkLWjqUCkiBfrSlGl6kpkxC4JQkK2ggqK4HAhJINAwCUFAZHQiQcD4hAOAKLRCYMQ8HYYmGpLiGYQA)

Comment: may I ask why in the end you're returning `(x: A) => S` instead of `never`?

Comment: You can test it yourself in the playground; if you do that, then the error message for a wrong function is "Argument of type `(a: number) => number` is not assignable to `never`", which doesn't really tell you how to fix it.  Compare that to the above error message of "`(a: number) => number` is not assignable to `(x: number) => string` so you can see that you need to change the return type to `string` (well, or the next function's argument to `number`, but ‍♂️)