# How to write a variadic function in Typescript with `n` different argument types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, variadic

I want write a TypeScript function that merges one or more transform functions.

A transform function has this signature:

```typescript
type Transform<T0, T1> = {
  (arg: T0): T1 | Promise<T1>;
}
```

And the merge function has this signature:

```typescript
type Merge = {
  <T0, T1>(f0: Transform<T0, T1>): Transform<T0, T1>;
  <T0, T1, T2>(f0: Transform<T0, T1>, f1: Transform<T1, T2>): Transform<T0, T2>;
  <T0, T1, T2, T3>(f0: Transform<T0, T1>, f1: Transform<T1, T2>, f2: Transform<T2, T3>):
    Transform<T0, T3>;
  // ...
};
```

Is there a way to write that type so that the function can accept any number of argument?

**EDIT:**

I want to add some example:
Consider these functions:

```
function toNumber(x: string): number {
  return parseFloat(x);
}
function toString(x: number): string {
  return `${x}`;
}
```

This call is correct: `merge(toNumber, toString)`.

But if we try to call `merge(toNumber, toNumber)`, the compiler
should emit an error because, the first argument returns a number and the
second one shall accept a number, not a string.

That is why using `any` in the function signature cannot work.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you. Link: http://shorturl.at/bltvS

Comment: how about something like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAZlC8UAUA6NBLAJgawFxQEMA7EASgQD5CSBuAKDoGMB7IgZ2CmAHdmBBAE4BzAK4BbCEWBt8cREnT4i4gEYQBAGijoATEtXry8KgG86UKAIjARAolACM9AL4MW7TsAAWViINESUjKwCMiKUMpiappQwRwC6ERCWmx6scAJSUam5pbWtvZOdM5AA
The idea is to use the spread operator (...) to accept any amount of arguments

Comment: @Yuval It works but it does not enforce the type of the arguments. The second argument must be a function that accepts the return type of the first argument...

Comment: @captain-yossarian There is nothing at [http://shorturl.at/bltvS](http://shorturl.at/bltvS).

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFAQwE4HMBcU1wgCUSAfPoVAD5QAKGA9gLYCWAzhADwEikCwAKEEAzAK5wAxsBYMETCNi4AVKBAAewCHAAmbWHAA0UAEqqNW3foDaAXVIoAdE8xY2eK04fGbRPMZHiUjJyClgQjs7YbtY+UADeglBJUBgQwKIYCC5sggC+goISsmzAKRBsogA2pcjyiijoeCUYLHBYJIjkaEYoAEZ4cKJMvQod5L0kAPSTUFaNUM2t7WQLwC1tPf1Qg8OjKzsjGDZAA

Comment: See the answer to [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173203/typescript-recursive-function-composition); translating that solution here yields [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WkvV9m).  Note that while it's easy to say "an array of one-arg function types where the return type of each element is the argument type of the next element" in English, it's significantly harder to express that as a constraint the compiler can really validate.  Depending on your use cases you might just want a series of overloads.