# Typescript type for an array of functions that each transform the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Let's say I have an array of functions that I want to reduce. Each function takes the entry from the previous function and returns a modified data.

For example:

```
const modifiers = [(req: TypeA) => TypeB, (req: TypeB) => TypeC, (req: TypeC) => TypeD];
```

Is there a way to set the type definition so it is dynamic and that it checks you are using the functions in correct order? i.e.

```
const funcA = (req: TypeA): TypeB => { ... };
const funcB = (req: TypeB): TypeC => { ... };
const funcC = (req: TypeC): TypeD => { ... };

// this would be fine
const arry = [funcA, funcB, funcC];

// this is also fine
const arry = [funcB, funcC];

// but this is an error
const arry = [funcB, funcC, funcA];
```

Comment: The only way I've seen this kind of thing done is like some of the type definitions I've seen in rxjs where they make a union of individual types cases for 1 item, 2 items, 3 items,... etc., usually up to ten or so. It's not pretty, and it's limited to however many separate cases you want to bother making.

Comment: I think @kshetline has the right idea. Something like https://tsplay.dev/Wzyn3m. Not pictured: automatically picking the right type based on tuple length.

Comment: There's no specific type in TypeScript which represents all and only valid "function chains" like this; you can represent it as a generic constraint, but it's fairly ugly.  Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173203/typescript-recursive-function-composition) and its answer; translating the code from the answer here yields [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5EGZN).

Comment: Btw, here https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose you have alternative way of function composition