# Trying to define a varargs/array of interrelated types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So, I'm working on a library to manage pipelines of transformations (from a source, through several "gaskets", to sinks)... and running into a problem specifically with recursive types. *Supposedly* that's been possible since TS 3.7, but I think I've run into an edge case that ain't.

```js
interface Sink<E> { seal():void; send(value:E):void; }
type Gasket<I,O> = (target:Sink<O>) => Sink<I>;

/**
 * The type of arrays of gaskets which go from a source type `I` to a sink type `O`.
 */
type Gaskets<I,O,Via=never> =
    // An array containing a single gasket from I to O.
    | [Gasket<I,O>]
    // A gasket from I to Via, followed by gaskets which go from Via to O.
    | [Gasket<I,Via>, ...Gaskets<Via, O>]
;

/**
 * `Join()` is used to cleanly wrap a single sink, or to assemble a sequence of
 * gaskets which goes from type I to type O and into a Sink<O> at the end.
 */
export function Join<I,O=never>(...arg: [Sink<I>]): Sink<I>;
export function Join<I,O>(...arg: [...Gaskets<I,O>, Sink<O>]): Sink<I>;

// @ts-ignore-error
export function Join<I,O>(...arg) {
  // ...
}
```

The above... doesn't work. Just `Gaskets<Via,O>` is wrong, but at least doesn't pitch an error... but when I add the spread-operator `...` prefix, it pitches `Gaskets is not generic ts(2315)` at that token, and `Type alias Gaskets circularly references itself ts(2456)` on the first line where I declare `type Gaskets` itself.

I've got a temporary workaround, but it basically means manually unrolling the recursion, and therefore supports a limited number of elements. Here it is unrolled to 7 gaskets...

```
type Gaskets<I,O,V1=never,V2=never,V3=never,V4=never,V5=never,V6=never> = 
    | [Gasket<I,O>]
    | [Gasket<I,V1>, Gasket<V1, O>]
    | [Gasket<I,V1>, Gasket<V1,V2>, Gasket<V2, O>]
    | [Gasket<I,V1>, Gasket<V1,V2>, Gasket<V2,V3>, Gasket<V3, O>]
    | [Gasket<I,V1>, Gasket<V1,V2>, Gasket<V2,V3>, Gasket<V3, V4>, Gasket<V4,O>]
    | [Gasket<I,V1>, Gasket<V1,V2>, Gasket<V2,V3>, Gasket<V3, V4>, Gasket<V4,V5>, Gasket<V5,O>]
    | [Gasket<I,V1>, Gasket<V1,V2>, Gasket<V2,V3>, Gasket<V3, V4>, Gasket<V4,V5>, Gasket<V5,V6>, Gasket<V6,O>]
;
```

Here's a simplified example of how it's intended to be used, from my specs...

```
describe("Join", () => {
    it("builds multi-element transformation chains", () => {
        const receiver = jest.fn((e:string) => {});

        const fromString = (i:string) => parseFloat(i);
        const toString = (i:number) => String(i);
        const increment = (i:number) => i+1;

        const chain = P.Join(
            P.Map(fromString),
            P.Map(increment),
            P.Map(increment),
            P.Map(toString),
            P.CallbackSink(receiver)
        );

        chain.send("5");
        chain.send("-2");
        chain.seal();

        expect(receiver.mock.calls).toMatchObject([
            ["7"], ["0"]
        ]);
    })
});
```

Now, I could just offer 2-argument or 1-to-N-argument forms of Join that only connects two nodes at a time, and write it up as `Join(gasket, Join(gasket, Join(gasket, sink))` and so on... but I'd really like to improve the signal-to-noise ratio.

Am I missing a trick, or this is fundamentally impossible presently?

EDIT: [here is an error-free TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEFQZwSwOwNahlUBDUAHANmgxgKagBmA9gE6gBua2ArgahenKAXACYC0pxXUAF3IE0AW1CjGUNAHMiA0qABGRKOwEA6ALAAoeAILli+IgGV4CADwBRAHygA3rtDQR2ABQBKAFxVSMDgBuZ1dOdxp6Am9rHz8A4J0AXwTdEAhQGTQoBAIBZFQMYzwFcgBPEmYMWERQAHcACxg8etBhQhgqRhZkOEw6PIFSzCI0TgryWrRyDlQFFlIBesNoCzrG5taCds7ZpYysnIEAciZ+voGhgm0dQeHQAHED3MsASQAaAHl7AF5QdwEpnIBN5zIhLF9PKBvvZQVYXrYUjpgAAqZHOZGgAAqe1uRF46HI5DQpSYxH22VyqAaTRaMkUxHIpHEVVIdHIhFAuNAAAMXtzOYoqqsudyPtzrqBkcBdFzHhSBFBXp83gA1ACM3zoiDgpFqcFVACZNdrdfqVQBmY0IHV61UAFitNrNAFZHabVQA2N16n6gXQASAAPqAANpyw5Kr4AXQDwbDTwESvVtjeDwTlnVqejsdD4ee72TqbziczKoNKbT8ozBqzthjOiDufTBbVFeLGbVhrb6bLqvN3arFtr9cb8arLYHEdL5aLPZrFsnzyHoBVdsXJbtnzrObHEYns8HnbL6+rfZPy9X583Kud5+dW5Hcfb+8rU6PM9fS-n-YPU-NqcvX8l2vW8gJLe8VQ9c8PQfXRERRNEdElHkACl-DgLx+RQUA6DUDgBVAPBsBEOBsHKWoiUwdAVjgGRiJohBU2YOYsjUUQlHoqoCAARwYOAOV4dFyUOKl1lpUgugZJlOUuUAXgIrkPhYfD9EFUBYXBew0AGPZ2A4CUpV0YgtWKGBSFYND4Ejb44AITpyFsdwNGcwFvFDDT4SjHx1IsV4ESMkyBDMiz0MjRznI0VzQwi4tFXeL5Uw06NvI8-ydFSMBsWw7DFjxUjyOJOTCNGUAOC2XBhGQAZFBgUQcAISQ4AEVNahgRZWTyFR4BkdAOPkRRRG0jY6Co3FUDwCg2gEMjrmM-igvM0BLLgMKnJc8gZDckNUqjUA4xihNFVGUo3mOiskrrFLfPhRwAxgYh3AJGQNGI2jFihb5fjVUBIScBt-WEAQ2VYQEQwABijBJ-USNhsDUZAHqel72Bkd7Pt+A0ftu-7AeBp7wajdxQbVLyoZhgg4aIP7-X9YiBjQGBsChfHAWRt6Wi4UASfQVANLOqH-TIchwimZBmdZ17UY50ADUCMXbF+MG5a4LgYF+gMaYmuBBAkAJxY2kMYF2rJP0TY7TrgUo0pp-0AUZ5nRACf4GewTwBcSDXcfIVg7ewMndA99Kg4y0BrAADzEeqcOkOQIt0LWdbaAgOkMNyNMEchut9Bw1FoLwHESVM1DCKBvAz7rPAcBPSGIl7SBkdwoE8RJknj8ydYAWTQTBhkoX5VqEUYoCF0Q3PcGBvBeTxoQ+SFoRCZ2NtyNPfIhKF7HcP6XBcXOPErgEl80XevECQuQh3vTx8n-fAVyDRi44f4iW1kfx88ZuQkSN3dDb7W8ik0QpghDdWZlfcutE572EwFMNQAAxbApBtJvwSAnPIWQgGZ1oqAiecA6DsUMJA9SwDaLIN-jreAeBhCNTyL8K+uD8HkEITAAA1GqREqDCL1AZqwX4y13ABi7j3Qw7gAEYIrm8AR3de7j34lQ9QngJENkEdIihcimoKMkUI4W6DiEyA0Q2JOKdyC6G-kHZo3D76XwAEQeisW7UAaRw7DGKKAKxAAOKxoBFrV1rggmQuggA) demonstrating the unrolled-type version of the code. The other definition for `type Gaskets<I,O>` can be substituted in to see the problem.

EDIT: [here's a refactoring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAEHcE8CcDNYEMC2BTA5AZ1EgxgC4CuSANqFgJYB2A1sAOZJa1oEWUPVLGxpYBYAFAhQAQQ51QlHElAAHUvjSh4Ae1igAbmSL9QG3NVBpqAEwC0a+BawE+qUOixYkDFQTWgARiqymCADphGgI0BGVQAGUaWgAeAFEAXiRqaAA+UABvYVAKNDIACgBKAC4tNUozAG5c-PNCnVI9UoSyiqraoQBfLuFRCSYWNmlZVXxPWGhVQzkqKUgAC0o8RdA+PDRKLX1U6Wp5InYCaHkVVLMZ2EgkWDMcTyM1AkXwyVpQJZW1ja2dh9eoCGrAI2AMR0Ox1OaGCQhOZ1AAHFmCC4gBJFJpAA0AHlMRlQElQIUCLd3ARSjE6HEcelioTMlT4mj0n0hP0wFFSbB2NYIAArPBkABeoAAUpVqLZONxeH4iPJ5BooWdBHDoaA0dRKAQ4gAVEwADzC5lkaQA2gBdTJEg1oY2me6gc2BV00eBvABKWKM0EtoAA-KBPaBSqBqGgdrAuvCVAAZZi6u0O02+q020DJk1Ol1u6gezQAMR97recf9QbjofDkfCbNjoBxyOGusRGcRRuzOGbqNS0BL+betMDjerEajMY1TZRbCwcQ79q7ztdgR7bCtPqZ1sJdS1OvnmUXjpwpaLI-NfZ9K4SxuQhDiWWdAGl9qBWNA+YXLWHpy24oXzSfbduh9Pt039MNxzrYRhAbMQsAAYUWJAaHnTtj2XV01wIDdolibciUfQDX3fPlEW-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-OvuFFufxCxTnht66I-ZfP-2r7r6giBQXxYB30-udV+2c3aUwUnwXK7AiQL1-v-cId9KAAGpmpsnfqsCyi1VLUH0p1fOhcDonzPvYOOWISoELOAdGgeAoEBGKOQ-BBcqG10gTlehjDiqUPCIUZgwCGAMJKh7KMTl0H2WoKvBoAAiAAbFIrWoBRA3jOIQUAUiAAcUiDDGATknGqqdpLCCAA) using @jcalz example code, which works the way I expect, but with some unexpected errors inside the `Join()` implementation. `type OGaskets` is utter witchcraft, and while I can follow everything else going on, that bit, and how it contributes to the whole, is incomprehensible to me at this moment.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Nn4AVW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/Wkj29m) meet your needs?  If so I might write up an answer (although it *could* be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53173203/2887218)).  If not, please [edit] the code here into a minimal reproducible example that shows the failing use cases.

Comment: @jcalz The question is updated to have an error-free playground instance of the manually-unrolled definition for `type Gaskets<I,O>`. Your second comment seems to *work*, but I do not understand specifically what `OGaskets` accomplishes.

Comment: I am happy to write up an answer to explain how it works (and why the goal is a bit more complicated than TypeScript can easily handle) but when you say it "seems" to work, can you verify that it fits your use cases (e.g., accepts things it should accept, rejects things it should reject, returns what it's supposed to return) or at least that it is close enough to be acceptable as an SO answer?  I'd hate to write up something explaining the whole thing and then find out that it's not useful or needs a significant rewrite

Comment: @jcalz I've substituted in the actual Sink/Gasket signatures and my `Join()` implementation into your `Join()` signature, and it does work and fail the way I expect. There's a couple parts that are confusing, such as inside `Join()` dereferencing arbitrary indices of the argument array to Join resolves to `Sink<never>` instead of to `Gasket`? So I've put a `@ts-ignore-error` in there for now. I'll add the link to the original question, since the URL refuses to fit in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to give `Gasket` and `Sink` some [default generic type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) so that I can just write `Gasket` to mean "anything that might be assignable to a `Gasket<I, O>` for `any` `I` and `any` `O`".  If you don't want to do this, you can give names like `AnySink` and `AnyGasket` to these types and use those instead.  These are mostly used for constraints.

```
interface Sink<T = any> { seal(): void; send(value: T): void; }
interface Gasket<I = any, O = any> { (target: Sink<O>): Sink<I> }
```

---

So the main problem with trying to write `Gaskets<I, O>` as any kind of specific type is that it would end up being sort of an infinite [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of every possible set of types between `I` and `O` in your chain of gaskets.  This cannot be written directly in TypeScript (there are no direct *existentially quantified generics* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466)).

Instead, the closest we'll be able to get is to write a type that acts as a *check* on a candidate chain of gaskets that ends in a sink.  If this candidate is `G`, then `AsChain<G>` will represent something like the "closest" valid chain to `G`.  If `G`s is *valid* chain, then `AsChain<G>` should be a supertype of `G`.  That is, `G extends AsChain<G>` will hold when `G` is a valid chain.  On the other hand, if `G` is an *invalid* chain, then `AsChain<G>` should *not* be a supertype of `G`.  So `G extends AsChain<G>` will *not* hold when `G` is an invalid chain.

This is necessarily more complex then any straightforward representation of `Gaskets` you were imagining, and is likely to be fragile and have strange edge cases.  Really, TypeScript isn't quite able to handle these kinds of recursive chains in an elegant manner.

---

Anyway the call signature for `Join` will look like this:

```
function Join<G extends [...Gasket[], Sink]>(
  ...arg: G extends AsChain<G> ? G : AsChain<G>
): any // return type to come
```

So if you call `Join(...arg)` then the type parameter `G` will be inferred as the type of `arg`.  If `G` is a valid chain, then the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `G extends AsChain<G> ? G : AsChain<G>` evaluates to `G` and everything is fine.  Otherwise, if `G` is invalid, the conditional type evaluates to `AsChain<G>` and since `G` is not assignable to `AsChain<G>`, the compiler will complain about some element of `G` that doesn't fit the corresponding element of `AsChain<G>`.

By the way, it would be great if we could just write

```
// won't work
function Join<G extends AsChain<G>>(...arg: G ): any
```

or

```
// also won't work
function Join<G extends [...Gasket[], Sink]>(...arg: AsChain<G> ): any
```

since both of those would logically be the same.  But neither of those work well with the compiler's type inference.  The compiler will fail to infer `G` to be the same type as `arg` and will end up complaining about even valid chains.  The conditional type above with `G extends AsChain<G> ? G : AsChain<G>` is the only thing I've found that seems to behave well.

---

So now the big issue is how to define `Aschain<G>`.  The idea here would be to look at a candidate chain like `[Gasket<I1, O1>, Gasket<I2, O2>, Gasket<I3, O3>, Sink<T>]` and move the type parameters around to ensure that they link up as a chain properly.  For example, `[Gasket<any, O1>, Gasket<O1, O2>, Gasket<O2, O3>, Sink<O3>]`.  If the former is assignable to the latter, it's because `I2` is assignable to `O1`, and `I3` is assignable to `O2`, and `T` is assignable to `O3`.  If one of those assignments fails, then the chain isn't valid.

Unfortunately it's quite a lot of [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) shuffling to do that.  Here are some helper types with brief explanations for what they do.

`Init<T>` and `Last<T>` take a tuple type `T` and split off the final element.  `Init<[1,2,3]>` is the initial part, `[1,2]`, while `Last<[1,2,3]>` is the final element which is `3`:

```
type Init<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer R, any] ? R : never;
type Last<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer F, infer L] ? L : never;
```

The `OGasket<G>` type takes takes a `Gasket<I,O>` and returns `O`:

```
type OGasket<G> = G extends Gasket<any, infer O> ? O : never;
```

The `OGaskets<G>` type extracts the `O` part of every `Gasket<I, O>` in a chain, and moves it to the next element of the tuple. So `OGaskets<[Gasket<I1, O1>, Gasket<I2, O2>, Gasket<I3, O3>, Sink<T>]>` should become `[any, O1, O2, O3]`.  We will then use these to become the `I` elements of the final `AsChain<G>` tuple.  Here's the implementation:

```
type OGaskets<G extends [...Gasket[], Sink]> =
  Init<G> extends infer F ? 
    [any, ...Extract<{ [K in keyof F]: OGasket<F[K]> }, any[]>] : 
  never;
```

I'm taking `G` and chopping off the last element that we don't need (`Init<G>`) and copying that to a new type parameter `F` via [conditional type inference with `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).  Then, after the initial `any`, I am [mapping the tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) `F` to another tuple of the same length where we are pulling out the `O` part of every `Gasket<I, O>`.  The `Extract<  , any>` wrapper is just to make the compiler understand that the mapped tuple will be something spreadable via [the variadic tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) spread operator.

Finally, `AsChain<G>` maps the tuple `G` to a new version of itself where each `I` in `Gasket<I, O>` is replaced with the corresponding entry from `OGaskets<G>`, and the `T` in the final `Sink<T>` is replaced with the last entry from `OGaskets<G>`.

```
type AsChain<G extends [...Gasket[], Sink]> = 
  { [K in keyof G]: G[K] extends Gasket<any, infer O> ?
    Gasket<OGaskets<G>[K], O> : Sink<Last<OGaskets<G>>> }
```

There you go.

---

Now `Join` has the parameter types from before.  Since it seems you plan to return a `Sink` from the first element of `G`, we can write out that return type:

```
function Join<G extends [...Gasket[], Sink]>(
  ...arg: G extends AsChain<G> ? G : AsChain<G>
): G[0] extends Gasket<infer I, any> ? Sink<I> : G[0];
```

Note that it will be impossible for the compiler to understand that any function implementation will conform to that complicated generic conditional type.  So you should probably not try.  The easiest way to proceed is to make `Join` an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with a single call signature as above,

And then make the implementation non-generic:

```
function Join(...arg: [...Gasket[], Sink]): Gasket | Sink {
  return null!; // impl
}
```

It should be easier to implement, since the compiler will only check against the looser, non-generic type above.  Or you can make the implementation even less strongly typed as `function Join(...arg: any[]): any { /**/ }`.  Anything you need to do to stop the compiler warning is fair game as long as you are reasonably certain the implementation is safe.

---

So let's test it:

```
declare const strToNum: Gasket<string, number>;
declare const numToBool: Gasket<number, boolean>;
declare const boolSink: Sink<boolean>;

const stringSink = Join(strToNum, numToBool, boolSink);
//const stringSink: Sink<string>

Join(strToNum, strToNum, boolSink); // error!   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Join(strToNum, boolSink); // error!   Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.

const anotherBoolSink = Join(boolSink); // okay
// const anotherBoolSink: Sink<boolean>
```

This all looks good.  The compiler is happy with valid calls to `Join`, unhappy with invalid calls, and when it's unhappy it complains with reasonable error messages that point to the problem.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4ghgZwNYWAHgJJQLxTgOxABooB5HPQgPgoG8oBLALigxIHsXyBfAbgFgAUKEhQAyg3xI0AFQoEQNXPWAs5fIUJHQM+BujkQAHsAj4AJgkogA2gF0lUQybOWoNgHRfJAMwgAnKAAlEgU7KAB+YKgWfAgANwCBYXBoABlEAyhjUwsrBXtHZ1y3T298P0CAMRJfAKg08Ki0mKg4xP9krVSyeGRUNBhHGGyXPNhEFHQFWor60hoo8liEpO7RUj6phEHRkqsyjy3UexIJKQccIShWPXQhvdcrOurI9xmoLw8AURN-OAAxuh6DYANKMfBQFAgdg+KBVOxcY7oKpgy7cUKEQrhFYdLopDYjXCbSaoHY2ZFoACMJAATFQSJSAMwkAAsDIm-XQAFYSAA2DnnaQAdioDiEAHoJVBtL0KDYPrS2fy7JoCdAAIIIADCAAs4JJdjknu4vsjTuJJEhLsp3ODJFCIDC4TBEbA0Y9xpSPi8yItrpypmgSVydkM0SQFq0hWgMgh0CHtoMqCmoNw1bKiVAtXqDfg0BTSegaVB6Yyi2gWVB2eWuWheVABWcrWhReLBFKZT0s4W64qOZSldWBxXWfzBS2BarBEIfABXfBAhjsSEAKXYhpGxvGh3NdmbFyoAAoA184P4AOYsLdjNw5-WbxawVr3vPJoQASmvNgADOFt24lK+mw1hPjGGA0N+f74vOi7AMua4bvgR5npeLC7kWFpCnYX6BqgUAAD6WlIUC0AG-ioHO-iQvgc4ADZ0QAhLwUCdgwAC2YB0UI6Yznx5gQACdHntAAIrvGUDxv4MjsAAcnO7HXhWUmSBeJC0exABGARUMkAlCSJUBifgEkaTJABC7DsHRSl1hp2n+CQmlWXREAELpQj6cJFFGeJwBQM51lCiwMaBa57n4kIxkSSp+AXkKFDrpIR5STJ8nsepCkWS5TkuUKH7JFK0X+bF8VWiFLalVQapJchqVyQpJD1eluVBVaBWsdKAT+Ow-iMTcTg9AA5KVQ2MFY+DsP5iAIAwF74HAmmuTK7BdqIQ32QEQ0eDVSEpcA0kNRlAV5e1LGdt1vX9TcMjDWFbn4GNDATVNeAILN82LctwCrbKG0KQ521qsVlBTbqASWW1JG4LVR5hfl53SuwSBwCAkrSiDBBgxDp1SBVUhoPd7lqmqQA)

Comment: Thanks; that's very comprehensive, and makes the constructs you're using make sense. It seems unfortunate that the error messages that come out when mismatching things read backwards to me (shouldn't the first error example complain about gasket 1's output number not being assignable to gasket 2's input string, or gasket 2's output number not being assignable to the terminal sink's input boolean?), but I suspect that's because of the witchcraft being invoked. I'll try fiddling with that to see if I can trick Typescript into doing it the other way around.