# Composition sequence type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Here's what I've done so far to implement function composition sequence using `Array.reduce`.

```
type Compose = <A, B, C>
  (f: (a: A) => B, g: (b: B) => C) =>
  (c: A) => C;
const compose: Compose =
  (f, g) => a => g(f(a));

type C_ =
  (fs: Array<(a: any) => any>) =>
    (c: unknown) => unknown
const c_: C_ =
  fs => fs.reduce(compose);

  //-------------------------------
  const f = (a: number) => a * 2;
  const g = (a: number) => a + 1;
  const h = (a: number) => a * 5;
  const s = (a: number) => a.toString();
  //-------------------------------

  const composedF = c_([f, g, h, s]);
  console.log(
    composedF(1)
  ); // "15"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAztAvFAPAQQDRQBCBMAfAFBRQAUAZgFw0CGjOAlFOqUQQOaPUARo0IcusMRSrUAxq0mwA3ORlwAdimBRVSVBEbxdaTpRq0+Cpp26861JmzbLyoSLAD6J6bRSsATn5MIFj2jExqIJYRpJKm0nJQAK5qANZqcADuagrJaZlqKuqa2u4GnuimPtZQPgB0fhAAJokyELKIyGhO5OQA9L0AtEPDI6Nj48OFGlq0nMyMaokIghB+llAAVFAATMqq01C8c6FQi8ur6wDUUACMe0VaABbHLKdLK2vVVlsArPcHKBeC3eFy+tWAcAAysA-ABLNS2br9CYo1EjHr7Yo6TpNABicxk7moAG1zIcCI8CCgALrdTFwAA2EFqDLgtlM2L0jVx1BubHITig-SgACIbj8RUA)

I needed to write

```
type C_ =
  (fs: Array<(a: any) => any>) =>
    (c: unknown) => unknown
```

with `any` type and if changed to `unknown` for instance,

```
type C_ =
  (fs: Array<(a: unknown) => unknown>) =>
    (c: unknown) => unknown
```

I have an error:

```
Type '(a: number) => number' is not assignable to type '(a: unknown) => unknown'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

So, my question is, is there any way not to use `any` in this code?

Edit:

Based on @jcalz work, now I tried to implement `p_` as pipeline application on the composition of functions.

I thought it's trivial, but for some unknown reason, the type doesn't work and allows the illegal operation against my expectation.

```
type compose = <A, B, C>
  (f: (a: A) => B, g: (b: B) => C) =>
  (c: A) => C;
const compose: compose =
  (f, g) => a => g(f(a));

type Lookup<T, K extends keyof any, Else = never> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : Else
type Tail<T extends any[]> = T extends [any, ...infer R] ? R : never;
type Func1 = (a: any) => any;
type aType<F, Else = never> = F extends (a: infer A) => any ? A : Else;
type AsChain<F extends [Func1, ...Func1[]], G extends Func1[] = Tail<F>> =
  { [K in keyof F]: (a: aType<F[K]>) => aType<Lookup<G, K, any>, any> };
type Last<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer F, infer L] ? L : never;
type LaxReturnType<F> = F extends (...as: any) => infer R ? R : never;

type c_ = <F extends
  [(a: any) => any, ...Array<(a: any) => any>]>
  (fs: F & AsChain<F>) =>
  (a: aType<F[0]>) => LaxReturnType<Last<F>>;
const c_: c_ = fs => fs.reduce(compose);

type p_ = <F extends
  [(a: any) => any, ...Array<(a: any) => any>]>
  (a: aType<(F & AsChain<F, Tail<F>>)[0], never>) =>
  (fs: F & AsChain<F>) => LaxReturnType<Last<F & AsChain<F, Tail<F>>>>;
const p_: p_ = a => fs => {
  const composedF = c_(fs)
  return composedF(a)
};

//-------------------------------
const f = (a: number) => a * 2;
const g = (a: number) => a + 1;
const h = (a: number) => a * 5;
const s = (a: number) => a.toString();
//-------------------------------

const composedF = c_([f, g, h, s]);
console.log(
  composedF(1)
); // "15"

console.log(
  p_(1)([f, s, g, h, s])
); // type error expected, but illegaly works as "105"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/ATAuE8AcFNgYwPYFtIIM6wLzADwEEAaYAISIGEA+AKBBAAoAzALmDoEMW8BKYTCkogHMWdAEYtiPPsDJTqtVnE5yZAbhrwEAOzShNKdNBaIDGXhvoMhKtr36DG7Ll3UaIMYABkECANYBXSBwAFSIAaWBoAA9QaC0AEzRgX2hwBAZgNi1wIgBRABszbC1oADdoACd+bAjo2ISklLSM4OAAfmBggG0wgF1gFgKMNyhYYLYAS3yQyJi4xMzsrt7qztn6ha6snOAAOn2JrQZK4AAlfo7TgeAS8or1EHdYADF-LTgARl5WDkXwG2yDzAo0ywVGOGeeUKWBuZUqq2e63mSXYLEOxwqwG4dj+7Sx1yG0CBTyxaDIAAtJloIUiGsAuq93h8iPtdozPstekQAOK0hbsj7Lb7jKYQijVCzAADe9Iih2SqXSwGevREvzYYJgEJ6KxsmugOG8fkCOG54SI2woFuy-AAvsSQZ42LoZnVkX9lqtWm66V1WeiTpDgAHMZ4Ll5rrdKg6PE6oqdoKB-BUtPqxd9ET6FnRWc6WNsVCGzniriwo-cqCMPHAAPrfGlZtCSrqov4AnasvAVCpscA4VsFnGWlaSxhoFiIgBkpIpVLFclH6rTzy6AAZdTi4wmkym006Xc9xUDEDo9LXjHXsAwktJr7sKtB4v44NA6CZUBgXJXHiDIJfcJmcwNM2A7ZO2LL7F2PZ9qB-xDjaI4KAOaZ0FOM6UocEJECK0yHhQXBrlysJ3PhdijteE7ANOeBkhh1KHioW6JsmqbgvuoA0tRtFzkGOFiuKFDHtoujAH+LB-t8ti3je-BSpKJ4ie+hjxIi2C1mOXCSg+O5aPoH6Ps8TgaPa37AAA9GZAC01k2bZdn2Q5NkaApegZNgrZaP4SCiJUNjAAAVMAABMQmnsAgjfB5Xk+RUfkANTAB8oUieSkW-J53m+UOAXAAArMleg3j8ZbRVl0hsLsoAIAAyqAFSHA4X4gBZjmtW1tmmS5enKap8A1nQXRWOFRDkkQaC9E1mg6Ag+TQLs+QIA48nIPpKl0B8mkgC45lmcAABEHy5XtnXCTNc0LUtCh-utXADUNaBCCNY0TcAGjbRZwIeJUFQIJi0QwHAsTxEQoj+HoUyzYIbD5OAwAAO6-b4STOvtHyrkdQA)

Comment: This is not trivial ... there's a healthy discussion about it here: https://dev.to/ascorbic/creating-a-typed-compose-function-in-typescript-3-351i (the proposed solution isn't complete) Just an observation: a truly type-safe `compose` function would allow `[f, g, h, s].reduce(compose)` but would give you an error on `[f, g, s, h].reduce(compose)`. It does seem like a tall order.

Comment: @geofh Thanks for your pointer. It looks like so. Appreciated to study more.

Comment: You can't get the compiler to see that reduce behaves the way you want, you'll need type assertions.  And the type of `c_` is complicated to represent.  The closest I've ever gotten is [this approach](//tsplay.dev/m0oZRN).  As such I'd say this question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53173203/2887218).  Let me know if you agree/disagree about the similarity; if you agree I'll probably close this as a duplicate. If you disagree you should probably [edit] this question to explicitly highlight the differences that make the other answer inappropriate here.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer! Since you kindly have provided the complete code corresponding to this question, I would be rather comfortable if you copy-paster your comment and the code then I could mark as the accepted answer here. Possible duplicate pointer will help to future readers, of course. But again, you provided the direct answer and I want to check the mark as the answer here. Thanks again.

Comment: @jcalz Please see my edit. Based on your work, now I tried to implement `p_` as pipeline application on the composition of functions.

I thought it's trivial, but for some unknown reason, the type doesn't work and allows the illegal operation against my expectation.  Any idea? Thanks.