# TypeScript: Is it possible to infer a type argument for each array element individually?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose we have following code:

```js
// a value, and a function that will be called with this value
type ValueAndHandler<T> = [value: T, handler: (value: T) => void]

type Params = {
    // not sure how to type it
    valuesAndHandlers: ValueAndHandler<???>[]
    // it's not the only field in the structure
    // so I cannot just pass array as variadic arguments
    otherStuff: number
}

function doSomethingWithParams(params: Params){/* something, not important*/}

doSomethingWithParams({
    // array of some pairs of handlers and values
    // each value is only related to its handler, and not to other handlers/values
    valuesAndHandlers: [
        [5, value => console.log(value.toFixed(3))],
        ["example", value => console.log(value.length)]
    ],
    otherStuff: 42
})
```

In this code I want the type of parameter of first handler to be inferred as `number`, and type of parameter of second handler to be inferred as `string`; but that's not happening (because I typed them as `unknown` in variable definition).

How can I type the definition so proper type for each handler is inferred individually?

I tried to add a default type for generic parameter, but it's not helping, because it's still the same for all the pairs.
I also tried to use `satisfies` without explicitly typing the variable, but that worked just the same.
I have also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173203/typescript-recursive-function-composition), but could not apply that technique to my case.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WG8Ykw) using mapped tuple types and a generic helper function meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Maybe it does? But I don't see how.
Updated the question. Actually the variable is not really a variable but a field in a structure. That structure is supposed to be passed in a function, but I don't see how I can make the function infer the type for me.

Comment: Either you have to make `Params` generic like [this shows](https://tsplay.dev/wgvB6W) (and inference suffers a little bit by having this inside a nested property, so you'll have to do a bit more annotating), or you need to refactor because there's no really good specific type that corresponds to `ValueAndHandler<???>`; you'd be looking for *existentially quantified generics* and TS doesn't support them directly.  You can emulate them like [this shows](https://tsplay.dev/WYeyvW) but it's a bit weird. ...

Comment: ... What is the use case for an array of these things if you don't know what the type arguments are? Presumably you can only do `vh[1](vh[0])`, in which case you might as well just expose only that functionality like [this shows](https://tsplay.dev/NnELaw).  Which one of those three approaches, if any, would you like me to write up as an answer?

Comment: Yes, first approach is just what I need! I was able to use it. Didn't think it's possible to use tuples like that. You can write an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which version, [this one](https://tsplay.dev/wgvB6W)?  If so that's essentially the same as the very first thing I posted and also the same as adsy's answer below... and I'm not sure I want to go through the effort of posting my own answer.  Or is it one of the other versions?

Comment: Yep, this one. It's not totally the same; the key difference is that I didn't know that you can expand a mapped type into a tuple like that

Comment:  Oh so you're just talking about using variadic tuple syntax `[...X]` instead of `X` syntax to hint that we want `X` to be inferred as a tuple type and not an unordered array?  I guess that's enough of a difference to matter... I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you actually want to keep track of the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments for each element of your array, then you have to make `Params` generic in that tuple type:

```
type Params<T extends any[]> = {
  valuesAndHandlers: [...{ [I in keyof T]: ValueAndHandler<T[I]> }]
}
```

Here the `valuesAndHandlers` property is a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) where each element `T[I]` of the input type `T` (at index `I`) is wrapped with `ValueAndHandler` to become `ValueAndHandler<T[I]>`.  I've also wrapped the whole mapped tuple type in a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) like `[...{ ⋯ }]`; this doesn't really change the type, but it does give the compiler a hint that when it infers the type it should try to infer a tuple instead of an unordered arbitrary-length array type (this is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#39094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094): "The type `[...T]`, where `T` is an array-like type parameter, can conveniently be used to indicate a preference for inference of tuple types").

To cut down on the amount of type annotations you need to write, we can make a helper function to infer the particular `T` argument given some `Params<T>`:

```
const asParams = <T extends any[]>(p: Params<T>) => p;
```

And we can use it like this:

```
let params = asParams({
  valuesAndHandlers: [
    [5, (value: number) => console.log(value.toFixed(3))],
    ["example", (value: string) => console.log(value.length)]
  ]
});
/* let params: Params<[number, string]> */
```

So `params` has been inferred as `Params<[number, string]>` as desired.

Do note that in order for this to work I had to [annotate the parameter types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) in the callbacks.  The sort of [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) that would infer the type of `value` in `value => console.log(value.length)` from its context doesn't work with inference from mapped tuples down inside properties.  Depending how much you care this could be mitigated by refactoring the `asParams()` function to accept the `valuesAndHandlers` property value as a separate argument... or really, any number of possible refactorings to tweak inference.

The main conceptual point here is that `Params` needs to be generic, and the rest of it is mostly just techniques to try to get desirable inference.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEENQN3AbBXApgGggOwCYVAM3mgYwBcBLAezVCIAtwjQB3E2WUAI0VALlkSyZpVqJAM7Q4SAFBEAngAdOANQmIAgpgAS4TLwBOAHgAqAPlABeUAG0YCRAC5Qh1LR2JdDgBQ2kDwwEpzUygyEgwAXUlpeU4ABXBdcABbESNQRAAPIkRMMW0ZSzDTCwBvSVBxWxF1DC1XXREHSwA6FuKrAElQEkoAa0QZMhxHMIdlW2rajD0jS3bC0ABfCIXJAgoRenAROITk81BUjKyc9HzCjzkHHaSUkwCzUzkAbkjeejl4m-2t6+SPUvK3kQVU02imbgaVjK5SsAFZUF4VA40PBEhxdPdTGs0CIyLwmrAyABzRG2JpEMgAMRI6T4HgAzH4-GFkNDypYAEQZJJyXgchFAhwbXTdImYrjrPGIAnE0lIAnZIk0ZnQ5Z+F7AABUoDeoA+u0hvxSlhRaLcqGFovmmuAkUkQA)

Comment: Is it possible to infer two type arguments that way?

Answer (score 3):

If you want inference like this you don't have much choice other than to spin up a wrapper fn :

```
function valueAndHandlers<T extends any[]>(
  ...arg:{ [I in keyof T]: [T[I], (arg: T[I]) => void] }
) {
  return [arg]
}

// This will return them wrapped in an outer array. Need to use varargs to get inference I think.

valueAndHandlers(
  [5, value => console.log(value.toFixed(3))],
  ["example", value => console.log(value.length)]
) 

// As used in your edit

doSomethingWithParams({
    // array of some pairs of handlers and values
    // each value is only related to its handler, and not to other handlers/values
    valuesAndHandlers: valueAndHandlers(
        [5, value => console.log(value.toFixed(3))],
        ["example", value => console.log(value.length)]
    )
})
```

Comment: Oh well. I was hoping that I'm missing something.
This all is more a matter of convenience; this function will be an interface of a library, so I don't want to make all users of my library call some functions just to pass parameters properly. I'd think of another way of passing this values and handlers I guess.

Comment: This is quite a common approach (wrapper FN). Usually, for users of a lib it's optional to use and just if they want intellisense. Of course as well as this you need a conditional type on `doSomethingWithParams` to ensure its *validated* to ensure they cant use anything when they don't use the wrapper (will show TS error if non-matching tuples, but no inference).