# Return value of useState() in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm making a hook to allow undo/redo in a React app. I want it to get the array of state values and setters.

This is how I want to call it:

```js
const myDogsState = useState<Dog[]>([]);
const [myDogs, setMyDogs] = myDogsState;
const areDogsSleepingState = useState(false);
const [areDogsSleeping, setAreDogsSleeping] = areDogsSleepingState;
const foo = useUndo([myDogsState, areDogsSleepingState]);
```

The problem is that I'm not sure how to properly set the type for `useUndo()` parameter. I want to make sure that the value and the setter use the same type. What I did so far is this type:

```js
type StateItem<Type> = [Type, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Type>>];

const useUndo = (items: StateItem<any>[]) => {
    //
};
```

However, using `any` here doesn't make much sense. Can I somehow infer the type of the first item and then use it as the type for `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Type>>`? Or maybe there's some easier way to do it?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75990761/typescript-is-it-possible-to-infer-a-type-argument-for-each-array-element-indiv