# Type a reduce function on prototype

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an object with data and an array of objects with methods, and creates a new "mixin" object by attaching all of the methods and data on a new object prototype:

```
type ThisFn<T> = (this: T, ...args: any[]) => any;

function mix<B extends {}>(base: B, methods: Record<string, ThisFn<B>>[]) {
  const self = Object.create(methods.reduce(Object.assign));
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(base)) self[k] = v;
  return self;
}
```

This seem to work fine when attaching methods that only depend on `base`, however, I would like them to be able to depend on the previously attached methods as well:

```
const named = {
  name(this: { _name?: string }) {
    return this._name;
  },
  setName(this: { _name?: string }, name: string) {
    this._name = name;
    return this;
  },
};

const surnamed = {
  surname(this: { _surname?: string }) {
    return this._surname;
  },
  setSurname(this: { _surname?: string }, surname: string) {
    this._surname = surname;
    return this;
  },
};

const fullnamed = {
  fullname(this: {
    name(): string | undefined;
    surname(): string | undefined;
  }) {
    return this.name()! + ` ` + this.surname()!;
  },
};

const foo = mix({ _name: undefined, _surname: undefined }, [
  named,     // Typechecks OK
  surnamed,  // Typechecks OK
  fullnamed, // Error: missing properties '{ name(): string | undefined; surname(): string |undefined; }'
]);
```

I've tried implementing the type of `methods` recursively as an accumulator:

```
type MethodChain<
  Base extends {},
  T extends unknown[],
  Acc extends {} = Base
> = T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
  ? First extends Record<string, ThisFn<Acc>>
    ? MethodChain<Base, Rest, Acc & First>
    : never
  : T;
```

However, I can't make headway with that. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not easy to write, you will need to do something like your `MethodChain` but getting inference to work out is annoying.  You could do it as shown https://stackoverflow.com/q/53173203/2887218 but I don't have the energy to rewrite that for your example and this is essentially a duplicate of that when it comes to the approach.  But I wonder, why do you need this instead of a Something like `mix(base).with(named).with(surnamed).with(fullnamed).build()` will be *much* easier to type in TypeScript. How should we proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz huh, thanks, completely fair re: this being annoying. For the chaining approach, would just use use a builder pattern, something like `return new MethodBuilder({...this, ...methods})`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... chaining is better than `...methods` because the chaining will always give TS that intermediate context and a new function call from which to continue, instead of trying to put it all together in a single function call and then somehow verify that the list of parameters is structured correctly.  Anyway I'm not sure how to proceed here.