# Typescript types for a pipe() function

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, pipe

Consider the following TypeScript code:

```
type operator<T> = (input:T) => T

const pipe = <T>(...operators:operator<T>[]) => (input:T):T => operators.reduce((output, f) => f(output), input)

const add2:operator<number> = x => x+2

const times3:operator<number> = x => x*3

console.log(pipe(add2, times3)(1))    //output 9
```

The pipe function simply pipes the input of one operator into the result of the next operator.

Now consider this new definition of the operator type:

```
type operator<T, U> = (input:T) => U
```

**How should the pipe function be rewritten** in order for the IDE to let me know if I am using the types correctly?

E.g.: consider these two operators:

```
const times3:operator<number, number> = x => x*3

const toStr:operator<number, string> = x => `${x}`
```

I would like this to work properly:

```
pipe(times3, toStr)(1)
```

And here I would like the IDE to warn me that the types are wrong:

```
pipe(toStr, times3)(1)
```

I can't figure this out, thank in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how [RxJS does it](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/f174d38554d404f21f98ab1079a101e80d777e95/src/internal/Observable.ts#L338-L404):

```
pipe(): Observable<T>;
pipe<A>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>): Observable<A>;
pipe<A, B>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>): Observable<B>;
pipe<A, B, C>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>): Observable<C>;
pipe<A, B, C, D>(
    op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
    op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
    op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
    op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>
): Observable<D>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E>(
    op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
    op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
    op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
    op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
    op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>
): Observable<E>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F>(
    op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
    op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
    op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
    op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
    op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
    op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>
): Observable<F>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G>(
    op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
    op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
    op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
    op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
    op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
    op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
    op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>
): Observable<G>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H>(
    op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
    op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
    op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
    op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
    op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
    op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
    op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
    op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>
): Observable<H>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(
    op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
    op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
    op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
    op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
    op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
    op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
    op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
    op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
    op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>
): Observable<I>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(
    op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
    op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
    op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
    op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
    op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
    op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
    op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
    op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
    op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
    ...operations: OperatorFunction<any, any>[]
): Observable<unknown>;
```

It's not pretty, but it gets the job done.

Comment: I see, but this is only going to let me pipe a finite number of operators

Comment: Yes, but source code being finite, that's not necessarily a problem. You just need greater typing endurance when declaring the function than the people who use it ;-). It's probably safe to say the RxJS team has investigated whether better solutions exist. If they had found a better solution, they wouldn't be using this one, would they?

Comment: While I know it isn't the same signature, it might be better to use a "builder" pattern.

Answer (score 5):

I know it isn't the same exact function signature but... might I suggest using a builder pattern?

[Typescript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgSzgUxgXhgHgIIBoYBCAfABQBmYAXDCQIbXYCU6RhzarA3gFAx8wAnZFACuAsDB79pMMtTIiwwKAnCYAwqQDm1EgA9qBdq3XNOg4WImIUJOgJ0wmLGFvJh7Wxt4C%20uXjJ8AEYiCAA2ACa6xrJgAXw%203IncoJCwoAC2cCAQqBg4%20MTuuvROMUYuUvxCouKS8TJysorKqmAa2roGMKYuzuY1VjCZ2bl2tA7UvRyxJG4TXr7%20gcGhkdEuFA2JySng0DC0ERHoNN1gIhlByAIxJACe1BdXNzF6MADUMPd7abIgAgytFgGBIVBgz2utxcAAMAG60MIiZDUAAknDAADooCAAMpQAQIMBuRg%20GG-A4iOAoASnEgQajQQnEmIQbEgACq1Ju6loY0Y3ApsDgAhAwGQEAgpxsyDoxxIACZvAFMWQ5RESAA2ZV8VXkAFAqAC3Vqqk040wTEhcIagWC1IHEViiUQBWnEY5WVm14qtVkA3Ai16o4a7VBtUhkgAVh1lutkRIdopIDCyExYRAbid4slWuVDpTaYzWdFOddecYQA)

```js
const pipe = <A, B>(fn: (a: A) => B) => {
    return {
        f: function<C>(g: (x: B) => C) { return pipe((arg: A) => g(fn(arg)))},
        build: () => fn
    }
}

const compose = <A, B>(fn: (a: A) => B) => {
    return {
        f: function<C>(g: (x: C) => A) { return compose((arg: C) => fn(g(arg)))},
        build: () => fn
    }
}


const add = (x: number) => (y: number) => x + y
const format = (n: number) => `value: ${n.toString()}`
const upper = (s: string) => s.toUpperCase()

const process = pipe(add(2))
  .f(add(6))
  .f(format)
  .f(upper)
  .build()


const process2 = compose(upper)
  .f(format)
  .f(add(6))
  .f(add(5))
  .build()


console.log(process(6))
console.log(process2(6))
```

Comment: While I can it working, it seems to me this will produce a deep stack based function which is what is usually avoided

Comment: Essentially, that is what pipe usually does (f(g(x))). It is essentially taking x function call layers and making 2x function layers. I absolutely agree it isn't ideal... however I kind of prefer it over n overloads where n is all possible function arities you want to possibly use.

Comment: You can see exactly this in Ramda for example: https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.27.0/source/pipe.js#L36
That is the fundamental concept of pipe (fold some list of functions).

Comment: Sorry, by "It is essentially" I meant that my method is.  My method is adding one additional function scope for the purpose of allowing the types to be accessible. There is potentially a way to improve this... however... I am not sure how with typescript.

Comment: Here is where Ramda would call pipe recursively in the reduce function: https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.27.0/source/internal/_reduce.js#L17

I had these a bit reversed but here is where Ramda does "x => g(f(x))" which is almost exactly what I did.
https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.27.0/source/internal/_pipe.js#L3

Actually, after looking at it now... it is almost exactly the same as what I did. You should get the exact same function call stack size. I am not sure what you think you are avoiding.

If you did pipe(A, B, C) you get "x => C(B(A(x)))" (with a layer between each)

Comment: It might be worth noting, this is also exactly what RxJS does:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/f174d38554d404f21f98ab1079a101e80d777e95/src/internal/util/pipe.ts#L33

Answer (score 5):

*Insipired by [Goblinlord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090576), [meriton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183406) and [this solution of `Array Sort`](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/20653).*

#### The code

```
type LastElement<T> = T extends [...unknown[], infer LastItem] ? LastItem : never

type Operator<A, B> = (value: A) => B
type OperatorA<T> = T extends Operator<infer A, any> ? A : never
type OperatorB<T> = T extends Operator<any, infer B> ? B : never

type PipeOperators<Operators extends unknown[], Input> =
  Operators extends [infer Item, ...infer Tail]
  ? [Operator<Input, OperatorB<Item>>, ...PipeOperators<Tail, OperatorB<Item>>]
  : Operators
type PipeOperatorsOutput<Operators extends unknown[]> = OperatorB<LastElement<Operators>>

function pipe<Input, Operators extends unknown[]>(...operators: PipeOperators<Operators, Input>): (input: Input) => PipeOperatorsOutput<Operators> {
  return input => operators.reduce((result, next) => next(result), input)
}



const add = (x: number) => (y: number) => x + y
const format = (n: number) => `value: ${n.toString()}`
const upper = (s: string) => s.toUpperCase()


const __TEST1__: string = pipe(add(2), format, upper)(1)
const __TEST2__: string = pipe(add(2), upper)(1) // Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
const __TEST3__: string = pipe(add(2), format)("") // Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
const __TEST4__: string = pipe(add(2), format)(1)
const __TEST5__: number = pipe(add(2), add(2))(1)
```

There are some places where I used `any` and `unknown`, however it should be more exact type. But so far this is only way I could get the code working.

*Please, don't beat much if it doesn't work properly.*

Comment: That's really nice! The anys and unknowns are totally fine imo: they only discard information that isn't needed in their narrow contexts.

Comment: Errhm, but where is the implementation for the pipe function? Or I am missing something? Right now it returns `[null, null, null]`;

Comment: @Alex, the question was about enriching IDE experience (TypeScript) not about pipe implementation. And anyway don't want to add any pipe implementation as it might potentially distract people, I want to keep this answer as short as possible.

Comment: I found out that the implementation is just a single line of code with modern JS, so I decided to added anyway ^_^/

Answer (score 1):

[Goblinlord's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67170880/6148332) is inspiring, if the runtime recursion is the concern, we may type erase the actual implementation so we can replace the recursion with iteration. Type erasing brings a risk that flaws could escape compile time type check but I think that is a price I am willing to pay.

```js
type Fn<T, U> = (i: T) => U
type Pipe<T, U> = { f: <K>(fn: Fn<U, K>) => Pipe<T, K>, build: () => Fn<T, U> }

function pipe<T, U>(fn: Fn<T, U>): Pipe<T, U> {
    const fns: Fn<any, any>[] = [fn]
    const p: Pipe<any, any> = {
        f: (fn) => {
            fns.push(fn);
            return p;
        },
        build: () => {
            return (input) => fns.reduce((prev, curr) => curr(prev), input);
        }
    }
    return p;
}


const add = (x: number) => (y: number) => x + y
const format = (n: number) => `value: ${n.toString()}`
const upper = (s: string) => s.toUpperCase()

const process = pipe(add(2))
  .f(add(6))
  .f(format)
  .f(upper)
  .build()

console.log(process(1))
```

Comment: Be careful with this. The shared mutable state is not apparent to users and will cause unexpected bugs.
If you define a common base, and then extend it twice, the second one will inherit the full chain of the first extension too. You'd need to clone the arrays in the compose function to make this workable.

Answer (score 0):

### Typescript [`abstract class (docs)`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-classes-and-members)

> extended from [Goblinlord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090576) answer

#### This is a strong safety of types solution

```js
// base.ts

type Operator<I, O> = (input: I) => O;

interface OperatorInterface<I, O> {
    build(): Operator<I, O>;
    compute(input: I): ReturnType<Operator<I, O>>;
}

abstract class BaseOperator<I, O> implements OperatorInterface<I, O> {
    protected operator: Operator<I, O>;

    public constructor(operator: Operator<I, O>) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    public build(): Operator<I, O> {
        return this.operator;
    }

    public compute(input: I): O {
        return this.operator(input);
    }
}

export { BaseOperator, type Operator };
```

```js
// pipe/pipe.ts

import { BaseOperator, type Operator } from '../base';

interface PipeInterface<I, O> {
    to<T>(nextOperator: Operator<O, T>): PipeInterface<I, T>;
}

class Pipe<I, O> extends BaseOperator<I, O> implements PipeInterface<I, O> {
    public constructor(operator: Operator<I, O>) {
        super(operator);
    }

    public to<T>(nextOperator: Operator<O, T>): Pipe<I, T> {
        return new Pipe<I, T>((input: I) => nextOperator(this.compute(input)));
    }
}

function pipe<I, O>(operator: Operator<I, O>): Pipe<I, O> {
    return new Pipe<I, O>(operator);
}

export { Pipe };
export default pipe;
```

```js
// compose/compose.ts

import { BaseOperator, type Operator } from '../base';

interface ComposeInterface<I, O> {
    from<T>(prevOperator: Operator<T, I>): ComposeInterface<T, O>;
}

class Compose<I, O>
    extends BaseOperator<I, O>
    implements ComposeInterface<I, O>
{
    public constructor(operator: Operator<I, O>) {
        super(operator);
    }

    public from<T>(prevOperator: Operator<T, I>): Compose<T, O> {
        return new Compose((input: T) => this.compute(prevOperator(input)));
    }
}

function compose<I, O>(nextCompose: Operator<I, O>): Compose<I, O> {
    return new Compose<I, O>(nextCompose);
}

export { Compose };
export default compose;
```

Enjoy Coding :)

Comment: for export as module :

on `// pipe/index.ts` `export * from './pipe'; `


on `// compose/index.ts` `export * from './compose'; `